# half-derivative of $x^2$

Tags: reference-request, fractional-calculus

I was given this problem to challenge me

$$\frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}x^2 $$

I googled wikipedia, and tried to follow the steps shown.

I got an answer of $\frac{16\sqrt{ \pi x}}{9\pi}$ **edited**

2 part question.

a) is my answer correct? 
 b) Reference request on a good paper/book on Fractional Calculus.

Comment: Your answer is wrong - just double check wikipedia to see the correct proof. There are plenty of references listed as well.

Comment: See example 2 at: http://epublications.bond.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1061&context=ejsie

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Related problem: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201335/bessel-and-cosine-function-identity-formula), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2/193914#193914). Here is a formula where you can use it to find the fractional derivative of a monomial $x^n$,

> $$ \frac{d^q}{dx^q} x^m = \frac{\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m-q+1 )} x^{m-q}\,. $$

The above formula was derived using the Riemann-Liouville definition for fractional derivative

> $$  f^{(q)}(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k-q)} \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \int_{a}^{x}\,
> (x-t)^{k-q-1}\,f(t)\,dt\>, \quad (k-1 < q < k )\,,$$
>   where $k=\lceil q \rceil$ is the ceiling of $q$.

See Chapter 2 in this [book](https://www.morebooks.de/search/gb?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mhenni) for details of derivation. In your case $q=\frac{1}{2}$, then the formula gives

$$ \frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}} x^{2} = \frac{\Gamma(3)}{\Gamma(\frac{5}{2} )} x^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{8}{3 \sqrt{\pi}} x^{\frac{3}{2}}\,.$$

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the edit.