# Is this derivative thing I found a defined mathematical concept? If so, what is it called?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers, fractional-calculus

I'm sure you're aware that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{x^{n+1}}$

Well, what if $n=\frac{1}{2}$?

$$\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{(-1)^\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2})!}{x^(\frac{1}{2}+1)}$$
$$\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}(\frac{1}{2})!}{x^\frac{3}{2}}$$
So would it be correct to say that:
$$\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{i\sqrt{\pi}}{x^\frac{3}{2}}$$
Or am I just an idiot? Please tell me. :)

Comment: [Fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) is a thing that addresses such questions. I don't really know enough about it to tell you anything other than what that page says (which does seem to agree with what you've written)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus; see also [Half order derivative of $ {1 \over 1-x }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391819/half-order-derivative-of-1-over-1-x) and the answer to [half-derivative of $x^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198901/half-derivative-of-x2?lq=1).