# Series Derived from the Fractional Derivative of Geometric Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fractional-calculus

With the geometric series:$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r} $$

It's normal to derive other formulas of series taking the derivative or integral of both sides of the formula. I wanted to see if taking the half-derivate of both sides could generate a new formula, but an error occurred and I don't know where.

Using the formulas from [Half order derivative of $ {1 \over 1-x }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391819/half-order-derivative-of-1-over-1-x) I get:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+1)r^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(1-r)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

Moving the $r^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ to the other side:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+1)r^{n}}{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})}=\frac{\sqrt{r\pi}}{2(1-r)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

Evaluating letting $r=\frac{1}{2}$ the sum = 2.0146... but the formula on the right = $\sqrt{\pi}$ which are clearly not the same. Am I making an algebraic mistake, is there something invalid about this intuition?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to believe that the half-order derivative commutes with an infinite sum?

Comment: @UmbertoP. nope, not at all. I would love a reason why it wouldn't work at all. I thought it should since it does for normal derivatives, but that intuition may not make sense in this situation.

Comment: In fact, the fractional differential operator is neither commutative nor additive in general.

Comment: @markviola That would explain the issue thanks.