# Help with Taylor polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the Taylor polynomial of order $2n$ of the function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+xy}$$ on  $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$.
Can anyone give me a hand please?

Sorry, i make a mistake, their should say "polynomial" instead of "series, i have corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Hint, for $|u|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{1-u}=1+u+u^2+u^3+\ldots.$$

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i correct now, i mean Taylor polynomial, or the order $2n$ doesn´t make any sense.

Comment: @Dimitri so only keep a fraction of the terms...

Answer (score 0):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279006/finding-coefficient-of-a-complicated-binomial-expression). Here is the general formula for the Taylor series of a function in two variables around the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$

$$ f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m y^k}{m! k!}\frac{\partial^{m+k}}{\partial x^m \partial y^k }f(x,y)|_{x=0,y=0} . $$

So, to get the order $2n$, you can consider the truncated series

$$ f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{x^m y^k}{m! k!}\frac{\partial^{m+k}}{\partial x^m \partial y^k }f(x,y)|_{x=0,y=0}. $$

You may want to show that

$$ \frac{\partial^{m+k}}{\partial x^m \partial y^k }\frac{1}{1-xy}\Big|_{x=0,y=0}=0\,\quad \mathrm{ when }\quad  m\neq n. $$

Otherwise, use Jonathan's technique to get the required series.