# Find $f^{(n)}(x)$ for $f(x) = 5x^4-8x^3+6x^2-1$

Tags: derivatives

I'm a bit lost and how I would go about creating a general formula for differentiating this equation. Find $f^{(n)}(x)$ for $$f(x) = 5x^4-8x^3+6x^2-1.$$

Comment: Is it $f(x)\cdots f(x)$ or $(f\circ\ldots\circ f)(x)$ or $f^{(n)}(x)$? I guess that's the latter now that I see you mention differentiation. Denoting the $n$-th derivative $f^n$ is very confusing and uncommon, I think.

Comment: You can use the general formula in this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198901/half-derivative-of-x2/199022#199022).

Answer (score 1):

Just take a few derivatives and see the pattern. I guarantee you will be happy after the fifth/sixth derivative.

Comment: I can see the pattern that is forming, but I'm having trouble with how I should write down the general formula.

Comment: What I've gotten so far:

Comment: 5(4-n)!x^(4-n) ect... something like that?

Comment: Did you get to the sixth derivative?