# Introduction to fractional calculus: problem with identity

Tags: complex-numbers, fractional-calculus

I can't see the next step:

$D^\alpha e^{ix} = i^{\alpha}e^{ix} = e^{i\alpha \frac \pi2}e^{ix}$

Comment: Did you forget to put the $e^{ix}$ at the end? Is this question currently incomplete? Please give some context: what is supposed to be shown here and what don't you understand?

Comment: Yes, thanks @HenryT.Horton

Comment: $i=e^\frac{i\pi}{2}$, is that your question?

Comment: Yes @Alex. I don't understand this step.

Comment: Then this will be helpful: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Could you specify which definition of fractional derivative you are using? The are several. Depending the one you are using $D^{\alpha}e^{ix}=i^{\alpha}e^{ix}$ is wrong.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198901/half-derivative-of-x2/199022#199022). You should know what definition you are using for fractional derivative. Check the link.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395501/closed-form-for-n-th-derivative-of-exponential/405345#405345).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Euler's identity $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$$
A complex number must be in the form:
$z = x+iy$, then $e^z = e^{x+iy} = e^x+e^{iy} = e^x(\cos y + i \sin y)$ and I want that this last equality be $i$, then, $e^x(\cos y + i \sin y) = i$ only if
$x = 0$ and $y = \frac \pi2$.