# Closed form for $n$-th derivative of exponential: $\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2a^2}{x}\right)$

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, closed-form

I need the closed-form for the $n$-th derivative ($n\geq0 $):

$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2a^2}{x}\right)$$

Thanks!

By following the suggestion of Hermite polynomials:

$$H_n(x)=(-1)^ne^{x^2}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}e^{-x^2}$$

and doing the variable change $x=\pi a y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, I obtain:

$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}=-2\left(\frac{y^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\pi a}\right)^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n}$$

and therefore

$$H_n(\pi a y^{-\frac{1}{2}})=(-1)^{n+1}e^{\frac{\pi^2a^2}{y}}2\left(\frac{\pi a}{y^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n}e^{-\frac{\pi^2a^2}{y}}$$

Finally

$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial y^n}e^{-\frac{\pi^2a^2}{y}}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi^2a^2}{y}}(-1)^{n+1}H_n(\pi a y^{-\frac{1}{2}})\left(\frac{y^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\pi a}\right)^n$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You may find the theory of Hermite polynomials useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials

Comment: @Nivalth I tried to follow your hint. Please help me to understand if I did it right or not. Thanks

Comment: @Nivalth Is that a confirmation?

Comment: I think it is correct, but let's hope for a confirmation

Comment: @JFNJr: By the way, what are the motivation of these problems?

Comment: You might be interested in [this topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18284) and [this paper](http://mathcs.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/Exp.pdf)...

Answer (score 4):

I obtained the following result using the Fourier transform:
$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2a^2}{x}\right)=\\\frac12\pi^2\,a^2(-1)^nn!\ x^{-n-2}\left({_2F_3}\left(\frac{n}{2}+1,\frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{a^4\,\pi^4}{4\,x^2}\right)\pi^2a^2(n+1)\\-{_2F_3}\left(\frac n2+\frac12,\frac n2+1;\frac12,1,\frac32;\frac{a^4\pi^4}{4\,x^2}\right)2\,x\right).$$

Probably, it can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Related problem: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397325/closed-form-for-nth-derivative-of-exponential-of-f). Here is a formula for the $n$th derivative of integer order of $e^{\frac{c}{x}}$

**Formula 1:** This formula is valid only for $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{ 0\right\}$.

> $$\left( \rm e^{\frac{c}{x}}\right)^{(n)}  = {{\rm e}^{{\frac{c}{x}}}}\sum _{s=0}^{n}
>   \sum _{k=0}^{n} \left( -1 \right)^{-k-s}\left[\matrix{n\\k+s}\right] \left\{\matrix{k+s\\s}\right\}{c}^{s}{x}^{-s-n},\quad n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \left\{ 0\right\} $$

where $\left[\matrix{n\\k+s}\right]$ and $\left\{\matrix{k+s\\s}\right\}$ are the Stirling numbers of the [first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) and the [second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) respectively.

**Formula 2:** Here is a [unified formula](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KZWIzZjIxZGQtN2M4NC00N2MzLTk1YmQtM2M2NmVhYmE4NzA5/edit?hl=en_US&pli=1) which gives a **complete solution** to the problem of differentiation and integration of real order of the function in terms of the [MeijerG function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

> $$\left(\rm e^{\frac{c}{x}}\right)^{(n)} = \left( -1 \right)^{n+1}{a}^{-n} \left( -1 \right) ^{n}G^{1, 1}_{1, 2}\left(-{\frac {a}{x}}\, \Big\vert\,^{1}_{1+n, n}\right)
> ,\quad n\in \mathbb{R}.$$

The last formula gives

1) derivatives of real order if $n>0$,

2) anti-derivatives of real order if $n<0$.

**Note:** The $n$th derivative of integer order of the function $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ has to do with [Lah nembers](http://mathcs.pugetsound.edu/~mspivey/Exp.pdf).

Comment: ${+1}$ Thanks for that remark. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Here we show that OPs approach is regrettably not correct and provide an alternative to answer the problem.

This answer is based upon the $n$-th derivative of the composite of two functions. It is stated as identity (3.56) in H.W. Gould's *[Tables of Combinatorial Identities, Vol. I](http://www.math.wvu.edu/%7Egould/Vol.1.PDF)* and called:

> **Hoppe Form of Generalized Chain Rule**
>
> Let $D_x$ represent differentiation with respect to $x$ and $z=z(x)$. Hence $D^n_x f(x)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.  The following is valid for $n\geq 0$:
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^n f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^nD_z^kf(z)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}z^{k-j}D_x^nz^j\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Let's denote for convenience only $c:=\pi^2a^2$.

> The following is valid for $n\geq 1$
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^ne^{-\frac{c}{x}}=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}k!c^{n-k}x^{-2n+k}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Using *Hoppes formula* (1) we obtain by setting
\begin{align*}
f(z)=e^{z}\qquad\quad\text{and}\quad\qquad z=z(x)=-\frac{c}{x}
\end{align*}
the following for $n\geq 1$

> \begin{align*}
> D_x^ne^{-\frac{c}{x}}&=\sum_{k=0}^nD_z^ke^z\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
> \sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left(-\frac{c}{x}\right)^{k-j}D_x\left(-\frac{c}{x}\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}
> \left(-\frac{c}{x}\right)^{k-j}n!c^j\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}\frac{(-1)^{n+j}}{x^{n+j}}\tag{4}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}(-1)^nc^k\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}x^{-n-k}\tag{5}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{k!}(-1)^nc^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^kx^{-n-k}\tag{6}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n+k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}c^kx^{-n-k}\\
> &=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k}c^{n-k}x^{-2n+k}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we apply Hoppes formula (1)
- In (4) we use
  \begin{align*}
  D_z^ke^z=e^z=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\quad\text{and}
  \quad D_x\left(-\frac{c}{x}\right)^j=n!c^j\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}(-1)^{n+j}
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we do some rearrangement
- In (6) we use the identity

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}(-1)^k
\end{align*}

- In (7) we replace $k$ with $n-k$ and set the upper index limit to $n-1$

> **Small examples:** $n=1,2,3$

Using formula (2) we obtain for $n=1,2,3$
\begin{align*}
D_x^1e^{-\frac{c}{x}}&=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\frac{c}{x^2}\\
D_x^2e^{-\frac{c}{x}}&=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\frac{c}{x^4}\left(c-2x\right)\tag{8}\\
D_x^3e^{-\frac{c}{x}}&=e^{-\frac{c}{x}}\frac{c}{x^6}\left(c^2-6cx+6x^2\right)\\
\end{align*}

> **Hermite polynomials:**
>
> If we consider *[Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials)* in the form
> \begin{align*}
> H_n(x)=-e^{x^2}D_xe^{-x^2}
> \end{align*}
> and apply a substitution
> \begin{align*}
> x=x(y)=\sqrt{\frac{c}{y}}=\sqrt{c}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}
> \end{align*}
> in order to obtain
> \begin{align*}
> H_n(x(y))&=-e^{(x(y))^2}D_ye^{-(x(y))^2}\\
> &=-e^{\frac{c}{y}}D_ye^{-\frac{c}{y}}
> \end{align*}
> we are in the same situation as above, since we have to calculate the $n$-th derivative of a *composition* of functions, which is not feasible with OPs approach. It could be done with *Hoppes formula* instead.

Let's look at a small example by taking $n=2$. In the following I omit most of the time  the argument $y$ and write $xx^\prime$ instead of $x(y)x^\prime(y)$ to ease reading.

> \begin{align*}
> H_2(x(y))&=e^{x^2}D_y^2\left(e^{-x^2}\right)\\
> &=-e^{x^2}D_y\left(-2xx^\prime e^{-x^2}\right)\\
> &=-e^{x^2}\left(D_y\left(-2xx^\prime\right)e^{-x^2}+(-2xx^\prime)D_y\left(e^{-x^2}\right)\right)\\
> &=-e^{x^2}\left(\left(-2{x^\prime}^2-2xx^{\prime\prime}\right)e^{-x^2}+4x^2{x^\prime}^2e^{-x^2}\right)\\
> &=-2{x^\prime}^2-2xx^{\prime\prime}+4x^2{x^\prime}^2
> \end{align*}
> Since
> \begin{align*}
> x&=x(y)=\sqrt{c}\,y^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
> x^\prime&=x^\prime(y)=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{c}\,y^{-\frac{3}{2}}\\
> x^{\prime\prime}&=x^{\prime\prime}(y)=\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{c}\,y^{-\frac{5}{2}}\\
> \end{align*}
> we finally obtain
> \begin{align*}
> H_2(x(y))&-2{x^\prime}^2-2xx^{\prime\prime}+4x^2{x^\prime}^2\\
> &=-2\frac{1}{4}c\,y^{-3}-2\sqrt{c}\,y^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{c}\,y^{-\frac{5}{2}}
> +4cy^{-1}\frac{1}{4}c\,y^{-3}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{2}c\,y^{-3}-\frac{3}{2}c\,y^{-3}+c^2\,y^{-4}\\
> &=-2c\,y^{-3}+c^2\,y^{-4}\\
> &=\frac{c}{y^4}\left(c^2-2y\right)
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (8). So, we can apply Hoppes formula or perform some equivalent calculation.

Answer (score 0):

By induction, the formula
\begin{equation}\label{g(t)-derivative}
\bigl(e^{-1/t}\bigr)^{(i)}=\frac{e^{-1/t}}{t^{2i}} \sum_{k=0}^{i-1}(-1)^k{k!}\binom{i}{k}\binom{i-1}{k}{t^{k}}, \quad i\in\mathbb{N},\quad
t\ne0
\end{equation}
was established in Theorem 2.2 of the paper [1] below. Consequently, the derivative
\begin{equation}
\biggl[\exp\biggl(-\frac{a^2\pi^2}{x}\biggr)\biggr]^{(i)}
=\exp\biggl(-\frac{a^2\pi^2}{x}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{a\pi}{x}\biggr)^{2i} \sum_{k=0}^{i-1}(-1)^k{k!}\binom{i}{k}\binom{i-1}{k}\biggl(\frac{x}{a^2\pi^2}\biggr)^{k},
\quad i\ge1
\end{equation}
can be deduced readily.

One can also compute the $n$th derivative of the function $\exp\bigl(-\frac{a^2\pi^2}{x}\bigr)$ alternatively. For more information on alternative computations, please refer to the sites from [2] to [6] listed below.

References

1. Xiao-Jing Zhang, Feng Qi, and Wen-Hui Li, *Properties of three functions relating to the exponential function and the existence of
   partitions of unity*, International Journal of Open Problems in Computer Science and Mathematics **5** (2012), no. 3, 122--127; available
   online at https://doi.org/10.12816/0006128.
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262657/945479.
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261764/945479.
4. https://mathoverflow.net/a/405003/147732.
5. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262516/945479.
6. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262498/945479.