# $\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}}$, what does it mean?

Tags: derivatives, fractional-calculus

I would like to know what these fractional exponents means in a derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ operator. Like, I've seen $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ but I don't know what $\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ means.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198901/half-derivative-of-x2/199022#199022).

Comment: [fractional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus)

Answer (score 4):

What you have is what is usually referred to as a *semiderivative*. I would say that this notation is a bit incomplete, since one also has to account for a lower limit, in the case of differintegrals whose orders are not nonnegative integers.

In particular, letting ${}_a D_x^{1/2}f(x)$ be the semiderivative, one possible definition is the *Riemann-Liouville* form,

$${}_a D_x^{1/2}f(x)=\frac{f(a)}{\sqrt{\pi(x-a)}}+\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\int_a^x \frac{f^\prime(t)}{\sqrt{x-t}}\mathrm dt$$

The semiderivative operator can be thought of this way: this is the operator that, when applied to a function twice, gives the ordinary (first order) derivative.

If you want to learn more about this, I would suggest picking up Oldham/Spanier's *The Fractional Calculus*.

Comment: is there a good reason to say it is "the operator such that ..." instead of "an operator such that ..." ?

Comment: But isn't the incompleteness of the same type as with the indefinite integral, where you also don't give an explicit lower bound to the integral?

Comment: @celtschk, Right, so I decided to be definite here; I'm not particularly fond of the indefinite form here.

Comment: @mercio, I now see that I only presented Riemann-Liouville and neglected Caputo; I might edit this later...

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}$ is the operator such that $\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}$$\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}$=$\frac{d}{dx}$, ie. $\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}$$\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}f$=$\frac{d}{dx}f$ for differentiable functions $f$, much like how $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}$. It is basically the square root of $\frac{d}{dx}$. For example, $\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}e^{ax}=\sqrt{a}e^{ax}$, since then $\frac{d^\frac{1}{2}}{dx^\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{a}e^{ax}=ae^{ax}=\frac{d}{dx}e^{ax}$.