# "Square root" of a derivative operator?

Tags: derivatives, differential-operators

I have been studying derivatives as operators on a function. Specifically, how we may write, for a function $f(x)$

$$\frac{df}{dx}$$

as

$$Df$$

where $D$ denotes $\frac{d}{dx}$. I've seen how successive application of an operator is seen as multiplying the operators together to give rise to a new operator. For example

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$$

can be written as $D^2f$.

What I have been pondering is this: Consider a certain operator $\Phi$, which has the property that

$$\Phi^2f=Df$$

*i.e* the $\Phi$ operator acts like a sort of "square root" of the derivative operator. This would imply that

$$\Phi f = h$$

and

$$\Phi h = g$$

where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are functions and that

$$\frac{df}{dx}=g$$

My question is, has such an operator been studied before? Does it have a unique name? I do not necessarily belive $\Phi$ to be unique, perhaps many unique operators may fill the role of $\Phi$. But can we determine if such an operator is unique or not?

Comment: You mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: @MattiP. wow thank you for that link. Can you please somehow convert it into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477888/what-does-a-half-derivative-mean

Comment: There is a nice channel on youtube by [Dr. Peyam](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoOjTxz-u5zU0W38zMkQIFw). He has several videos related to the fractional calculus and the reasoning behind defining some of the concepts. [Here is a playlist for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaAhCTDc6oA&list=PLJb1qAQIrmmB_ma3YrfuOXTPOQawokYV_)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a body of research about this. The correct term is Fractional Calculus and you can find more about it here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus