# What is the half derivative of $i$ the imaginary unit?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What is $\displaystyle\frac{d^{(1/2)}}{dx^{(1/2)}}(i)$ I saw some youtube videos about half derivatives, and was curious if this has an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "half derivative" mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477888/what-does-a-half-derivative-mean)

Comment: Can you tell us what a "half derivative" is.  And you can have half derivatives of constants.   What is $\frac {d^{\frac 12}}{dx^{\frac 12}} 27$?

Comment: Wouldn't $\frac {d^{k}}{dx^k} c = 0$ for all $k$ and all constants $c$.  $i$ is in no way a function and the fact that is imaginary does not change that it is a constant.

Comment: That must be a function such that its half derivative is zero.

Comment: @fleablood: this is true for all integers $k\ge1$, but for $k=\frac12$ we don't know.

Comment: If derivative is **Riemann–Liouville** then answer is: $\displaystyle\frac{d^{(1/2)}}{dx^{(1/2)}}(i)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\sqrt{s} \left(\mathcal{L}_x[i](s)\right)\right](x)=\frac{i}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{x}}$