# A general theory of fractional operations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, fractional-calculus, fractional-iteration

This post is motivated by observing that certain operators have "fractional analogs".

For example, let $f: R\to R$ be a differentiable function.
The differential operator $D^{1}(f)$ produces a new function.
For positive integers $n\in N$, we can define the nth derivative: $D^{n}(f)\equiv D^{1}\circ D^{n-1}(f)$.
The half-derivative is defined to be the function $D^{\frac{1}{2}}(f)\equiv H(f)$ where $H\circ H(f)=D^{1}(f)$.
More generally, the [qth derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198901/half-derivative-of-x2) is defined $D^{q}(f)$ for $q \geq 0$.
Conveniently, this fractional derivative definition agrees w/ the usual definition when $q\in N$.

The goal of this post is to try to think about fractional operators more generally. That is many operator definitions $F^{n}(f)$ work for positive integers, but when are they extended?

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
\text{Operation} & \text{Discrete Index set} & \text{Continuum Index set} & \text{Note}
\\ \hline
%
+(a,b) & \sum_{i \in I} f(i) & \int_{i \in I} f(i) di &   
\\ \hline
%
*(a,b) & \prod_{i \in I} f(i) & \exp\left( \int_{i \in I} \ln f(i) di \right) & \text{If A is a matrix } A^{1/2}\equiv\{M:M^2=A\}  
\\ \hline
%
  & n!\equiv \underset{i\in{1,\dots,n}}{\prod i} & x!\equiv \Gamma(x+1) & \Gamma(n+1)=n! \text{ when n is a positive integer}   
\\ \hline 
%
\circ(f,g) & f^{n}(x)\text{ , } n \in N & f^{a}(x)\text{ , } a \in R &  f^{1/2}(x)\equiv\{g:g^2(x)=f(x)\} 
\\ \hline
%
D^{1}(f) & D^{n}(f)\text{ , } n \in N & D^{a}(f)\text{ , } a \in R_+ &  D^{1/2}(f)\equiv\{g:D^2(g)=f\} 
\\ \hline
%
\end{array}

What are other known operations which can be extended/generalized in this way?

Comment: Fractional could mean things besides $\mathbb R$. For instance the Skolem-Mahler-Lech theorem can be proven by interpolating function iteration to include $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: Integration is not a fractional operation for summation. Your $\sum_{i \in I} f(i)$ and $\int_{i \in I} f(i) di$ are not in general equal for integer $i$. But see [Euler-Maclaurin summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) for a relation between them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : X \rightarrow X$ be an endofunction. Modulo issues of existence and uniqueness:

- $f^{-n}$ can be defined as the function such that $f^{-n} \circ f^n = f^n \circ f^{-n} = \mathrm{id}_X$.
- $f^{1/n}$ can be defined as the function such that $(f^{1/n})^n = f$.
- Let $a$ be a sequence of rationals. $f^{\lim_n a_n}$ can be defined as $\lim_n f^{a_n}$.

We can also try to find a function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X \rightarrow X$ such that $g(n) = f^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ while satisfying e.g. asymptotic properties (see the case of the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler%27s_definition_as_an_infinite_product)) and properties like analyticity (see the example of [extending tetration to complex heights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Complex_heights)).

See also [fractional iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Fractional_iterates_and_flows,_and_negative_iterates) and [fractional dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional-order_system) for a general theory.