# How can I prove my conjecture for the coefficients in $t(x)=\log(1+\exp(x)) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, dirichlet-series

I'm considering the transfer-function
$$ t(x) = \log(1 + \exp(x)) $$
and find the beginning of the power series (simply using Pari/GP) as
$$ t(x) = \log(2) + 1/2 x + 1/8 x^2 – 1/192 x^4 + 1/2880 x^6 - \ldots $$
Examining the pattern of the coefficients I find the much likely composition
$$ t(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\eta(1-k) \over k! }x^k $$ where $ \eta() $ is the Dirichlet eta-(or "alternating zeta") function.
I'm using this definition in further computations and besides the convincing simplicitiness of the pattern the results are always meaningful. However, I've no idea how I could prove this description of the coefficients.

Q: Does someone has a source or an idea, how to do such a proof on oneself?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Faadi Bruno's forlmula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula).

Comment: Yes, but I find it a much complicated one. When I study iteration of functions and can use a Carleman-matrix-epression (and the formal powers of that Carleman-matrices) then I could always avoid to involve into that formula. I know of a handful of articles which put Carleman/Bell-matrix and Faa-di-Bruno together, as for instance Aldrovandi/Freitas but I wouldn't see the solution for the proof for the decryption of the transfer-function $t(x)$ in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge0$, by virtue of the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the Bell polynomials of the second kind $B_{n,k}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
t^{(n)}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n(\ln u)^{(k)} B_{n,k}\bigl(u'(x),u''(x),\dotsc,u^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr), \quad u=u(x)=1+\operatorname{e}^x\\
&=(\ln u)B_{n,0}\bigl(\operatorname{e}^x,\operatorname{e}^x,\dotsc,\operatorname{e}^x\bigr)
+\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln u)^{(k)} B_{n,k}\bigl(\operatorname{e}^x,\operatorname{e}^x,\dotsc,\operatorname{e}^x\bigr)\\
&=\begin{cases}
\ln u, &n=0\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln u)^{(k)} B_{n,k}\bigl(\operatorname{e}^x,\operatorname{e}^x,\dotsc,\operatorname{e}^x\bigr), & n>0
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\ln(1+\operatorname{e}^x), &n=0\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(1+\operatorname{e}^x)^{k}} \operatorname{e}^{kx}B_{n,k}(1,1,\dotsc,1), & n>0
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\ln(1+\operatorname{e}^x), &n=0\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(1+\operatorname{e}^x)^{k}} \operatorname{e}^{kx}S(n,k), & n>0
\end{cases}\\
&\to
\begin{cases}
\ln2, &n=0\\
\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{2^{k}}S(n,k), & n>0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
as $x\to0$, where $S(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Consequently, we have
\begin{equation*}
t(x)=\ln2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{2^{k}}S(n,k)\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}, \quad x<0.
\end{equation*}
Since
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(k-1)!}{2^{k}}S(n,k)
=(-1)^{n+1} (2^n-1) \zeta (1-n), \quad n\ge1,
\end{equation*}
we arrive at
\begin{equation*}
t(x)=\ln2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2^n-1) \zeta (1-n)}{n!}x^n, \quad x<0.
\end{equation*}
Since
\begin{equation*}
\eta (1-n)=(-1)^{n+1}(2^n-1) \zeta (1-n), \quad n\ge2,
\end{equation*}
we finally conclude that
\begin{equation*}
t(x)=\ln2+\frac{1}2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\eta(1-n)}{n!}x^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\eta(1-n)}{n!}x^n, \quad x<0.
\end{equation*}
For details of the notations and notions used above, please read the following references.

1. Wei-Shih Du, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Several recursive and closed-form formulas for some specific values of partial Bell polynomials*, Advances in the Theory of Nonlinear Analysis and its Applications **6** (2022), no. 4, 528--537; available online at https://doi.org/10.31197/atnaa.1170948.
2. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
3. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
4. Dongkyu Lim and Feng Qi, *Increasing property and logarithmic convexity of two functions involving Dirichlet eta function*, Journal of Mathematical Inequalities **16** (2022), no. 2, 463--469; available online at https://doi.org/10.7153/jmi-2022-16-33.
5. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
6. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
7. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Comment: Uff!! Well, that looks much competent, thank you very much for this big effort! I'll take it for slow digestation, because now, nearly 10 years after asking this question, I'm 70 years old and unfortunately have no more that strong energy as in 2013. But I'm happy that I got it correct when I derived this from patterns... Thank you very much again!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Today I found another two simpler and elementary proofs of your conjecture.

Comment: Hello Dr.Prof  Qi - thanks for your second ping in this matter. Now I remember, where I had used this; this is in "uncompleting the Gamma" (function) https://go.helms-net.de/math/musings/UncompletingGamma.pdf in Chap 4, pg 13ff, this has perhaps further inspiring ideas, since I considered this in connection of indefinite summation. Since the analysis of (partial) Bell-polynomials is nearly identical to the analysis of (and with) Carlemanmatrices that essay (and others of mine) might be as well of interest; I've been experimented with functions by that Carleman-ansatz a couple of years ago.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Would you mind that I send an e-mail to you? If yes, please let me know your e-mail address. If yes, I will send my proofs of your conjecture to you.

Comment: That would be nice. My adress is gottfried.helms (at) t-online.de (no more the university adress) - thank you very much!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Sent a file to your gottfried.helms (at) t-online.de

Comment: Wen-Hui Li, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi. Expanding the function $\ln(1+\operatorname{e}^x)$ into power series in terms of the Dirichlet eta function and the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Carpathian Mathematical Publications Vol. 15, (2023), in press; available online at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/369476475

Comment: Ah, thank you very much Dr. Qi (@qifeng618) for the notification. I'll go to get it downloaded

Answer (score 13):

The [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) is given by $\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n^{-s}$, but this converges only for $s$ with positive real part, and you are proposing to use its behavior for negative integers.  A globally convergent series for $\eta$ can be derived using the Riemann zeta function (cf. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)):
$$
\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}{{n}\choose{k}}(k+1)^{-s}.
$$
Using this expansion allows us to write $\eta(1-k)$ as
$$
\eta(1-k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^{j}{{n}\choose{j}}(j+1)^{k-1}.
$$

Your power series is then
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\eta(1-k)x^k}{k!}
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^{j}{{n}\choose{j}}(j+1)^{k-1}\left(\frac{x^{k}}{k!}\right) \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j+1}{{n}\choose{j}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(x(j+1)\right)^{k}}{k!} \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{j+1}{{n}\choose{j}}\left(e^x\right)^{j+1} \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\int_{-e^{x}}^{0} dy\sum_{j=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{j}}y^{j} \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\int_{-e^{x}}^{0}\left(1+y\right)^{n}dy \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\frac{\left(1+y\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}\Bigg\vert_{-e^x}^{0} \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^{-(n+1)}\frac{1-\left(1-e^x\right)^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&=&f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - f\left(\frac{1-e^x}{2}\right),
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\log \left(1-z\right).$$
Putting this together, we find
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\eta(1-k)x^k}{k!} = -\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\log\left(\frac{1+e^x}{2}\right)=\log\left(1+e^x\right),
$$
as you conjectured.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot -this shall give me much to chew on and to study...  to use this sequence of steps for other, but related, situations; it looks much helpful, indeed!

Answer (score 4):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327416/solve-the-sequence-u-n-1-fracu-1n-fracu-2n-1-ldots-frac/328401#328401), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2/193914#193914), [(III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397325/closed-form-for-nth-derivative-of-exponential-of-f), [(IV)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383068/finding-the-expansion-of-arcsinz2). Here is a formula for the nth derivative of the function $\ln(1+e^{x})$ at the point $x=0$

> $$ \left( \ln(1+e^{x})\right)^{(n)}= \sum _{k=1}^{n}\begin{Bmatrix} n\\k \end{Bmatrix} \left( -1 \right)^{k+1}2^{-k}\,
> \Gamma\left( k \right),\quad n \in \mathbb{N}, $$

where $\begin{Bmatrix} n\\k \end{Bmatrix} $ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind. The above formula allows us to construct the Taylor series of the function as

> $$ \ln(1+e^x) = \ln(2)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum _{k=1}^{n}\begin{Bmatrix} n\\k \end{Bmatrix} \left( -1 \right)^{k+1}\, 2^{-k}\,\Gamma\left( k \right) \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

Comment: can you prove the first assertion?

Comment: @nbubis: I'll try to do this later.

Comment: (where the curly braces mean the Stirling numbers 2'nd kind)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: Yes, I'll add this.

Comment: arrgh - that Stirling numbers 2'nd kind rang my alarm. It's just to use the Carleman-matrices for $x\to \exp(x)-1$, then $ x \to x+1 $ and the first column of that for $x \to \log(1+x) $. This gives the decomposition in Stirling-numbers 2nd and 1st kind and binomial-coefficients.     Well, but after that: how is that the sequence of Dirichlet-etas?