# Closed form for a binomial containing a differential operator

Tags: binomial-coefficients, differential-operators

Is there a closed form for $(x + D)^n$ where D is the differential operator with respect to x?

Avi's comment in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318135/finding-an-expression-for-nth-derivative/318184#318184) post helped me understand this expression a bit better, but I'm still curious if you can write it out with sums and binomial coefficients in some clever way.

Edit: I ran into this expression while deriving properties of the Hermite polynomials so I could use them in the context of a harmonic oscillator. This question is purely out of mathematical curiosity.

Comment: Why not explain what you tried and say where you're stuck?

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: This operator is proportional to the lowering operator for the quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator. As such it has a lot of really nice properties, for example $\exp(-\alpha(x+D))$ is a translation operator in phase space. But I don't know if $(x+D)^n$ has a simple expression.

Comment: My gut tells me there isn't. I haven't seen it written out, but I figured I'd ask. I thought maybe there was a fancy series of named numbers that you could use, or something similar to that.