# Closed form for $n$th derivative of exponential of $f$

Tags: derivatives, closed-form, partial-derivative

What is the closed form for:

$$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\exp(f(x))=\exp(f(x))\cdot[????]$$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2).

Comment: Another [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/what-is-the-formula-for-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x-arctan-x-sec-x-and-tan-x).

Comment: By the way, how did you meet this problem?

Comment: This question duplicates [General formula or a pattern for the $n$
th derivatives of $e^f(x)$
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441522/622884)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a double finite sum solution, but just using the series expansion of $e^f$ gives an infinite sum

Answer (score 10):

See the Wikipedia articles titled [Exponential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) and [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).  Both involve enumerations of set partitions.

It's simpler to express with $\dfrac{\partial^n}{\partial x_1\,\partial x_2\,\cdots\,\partial x_n}$ than with $\dfrac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}$, but after doing that, just declare $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to be all the same variable and then drop the subscripts and collect like terms.  So for example:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_1\,\partial x_2\,\partial x_3} e^{f(x)} \\[10pt]
& = e^{f(x)}\left(\frac{\partial^3 f(x)}{\partial x_1\,\partial x_2\,\partial x_3} \right. \\[10pt]
& {} + \underbrace{\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_2\,\partial x_3}}
+ \underbrace{\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_2\,\partial x_3}}
+ \underbrace{\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_3} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x_1\,\partial x_2}} \\[10pt]
& \left.{} + \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1} \cdot \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_2} \cdot \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_3} \right).
\end{align}

You get one term for each partition of the set of three variables.  For the fourth derivative, there's one for each of the $15$ partitions of the set of four variables, etc.

Consequently
$$
\frac{\partial^3 f(x)}{\partial x^3} = e^{f(x)}\left( \frac{\partial^3 f(x)}{\partial x^3} + 3 \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial x^2} + \left( \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \right)^3  \right),
$$
and similarly with the fourth derivative the sum of the coefficients is $15$, etc.

**Later note:** Here's a summary of the proof: Mathematical induction on the order of the derivative.

Comment: You gave it more thinking than I did :P but yes, brilliant solution. +1

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : Thank you.

Comment: ....um.... I think we're going to have to regard "$f(x)$" as a function of all $3$, or all $n, variables.

Comment: I admit that I feel you have the exact formula to compute this because I computed the first few examples and it looks right, but I don't understand how to go in the details. How do you define a function $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $g(x,\dots,x) = f(x)$ and everything "works" nicely?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva : I'm not so sure that's really necessary.  You just need to know that the same argument that works when you differentiate with respect to $x_{n+1}$ in the inductive step also works if $x_{n+1}$ happens to be one of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: My question was more like... "what's the inductive step"?

Comment: I wrote something about this on another occasion.  (I mangled the formula on the first page but got it right later in the paper.):  http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v13i1r1/pdf

Comment: I believe the right way to formally do that inductive step is to write $g(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}n$ and to consider $e^{f(g(x_1,\dots,x_n))}$. Computing $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x_1 \dots \partial x_n} e^{f(g(x_1,\dots,x_n))}$ will allow us to have the appropriate combinatorial interpretation times a factor of $\frac 1{n^n}$ that will appear on each term, but we can apply the chain rule and get rid of that $n^n$ factor on the other hand. The chain rule will allow us to write $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial g^n} e^{f(g)}$ and we will recover our identity there.

Answer (score 5):

So we know that if $f,g$ are infinitely differentiable, we can compute
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( e^{f(x)} g(x) \right) = \left( f'(x) e^{f(x)} \right) g(x) + e^{f(x)} g'(x) =  e^{f(x)} \left( f'(x) g(x) + g'(x) \right).
$$ 
So since $e^{f(x)} = e^{f(x)} \left( 1 \right)$ and that we know that all derivatives of $e^{f(x)}$ are going to be of the form $e^{f(x)}g(x)$ for some functions $g$, we can apply the above formula and assume that 
$$
\frac {d^n}{dx^n} e^{f(x)} = e^{f(x)} g_n(x), \qquad g_0(x) = 1.
$$
We can use the formula found above to find a recurrence relation for $g_n(x)$ : 
$$
g_n(x) = f'(x) g_{n-1}(x) + g_{n-1}'(x), \qquad g_0(x)
$$
The formula from Wolfram Alpha provided by Integral looks wrong because there should be no $f(x)^j$ in there ; it's impossible to make the function $f$ appear in the factor because all derivatives of $e^{f(x)}$ have the derivatives of $f$ appear in the factor (i.e. the function $g_n$), but never the function $f$ itself.

If you wanted this for yourself to compute higher derivatives of $e^{f(x)}$ I suggest you just apply the recurrence relation to get the first few. For a general formula I must admit I don't know. Would require more thinking.

Comment: It may only look wrong because 1) some powers of $f$ are compensated by $f^j$ which comes next and 2) there are many similar terms in the double sum which can cancel each other.

Comment: I really didn't understand your comment to be honest. It looks wrong to me because there should be no power of $f$ *at all* in the expression of the derivatives...

Comment: of course. What I'm saying is that, although at first sight Wolfram answer contains terms containing powers of $f$, such terms may cancel each other in the sum.

Comment: @O.L. What I'm saying is even if it was right, it "feels" wrong because when I look at that formula I almost feel like I'm better off computing it by hand. I mean, there's a sum of sums in there. That must be a hell of a lot cancellation ; I believed there was a more brilliant way to think about this ; Michael Hardy found it.

Comment: Well I completely agree with that - it is clear from the very beginning that the most efficient formula should be given by a sum over partitions.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how to get this result, but check wolfram's solution. It's exactly what you are looking for.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5En%2Fdx%5En%28e%5E%28f%28x%29%29%29

Comment: Just use induction, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: Wolfram's solution looks wrong, it's literally impossible that an $f(x)^j$ factor appears anywhere in there. When you differentiate $e^{f(x)}$, an $f'(x)$ factor drops, so the factor can only depend on the derivatives of $f$ but not $f$ itself..

Comment: I was trying to use induction and failing right now...

Comment: Sorry about my comment. Doesn't look easy ; but that's because I thought the Wolfram Alpha formula was right. "Plugging it in" should have been easy.

Answer (score 3):

Related problem:[(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307274/how-can-i-prove-my-conjecture-for-the-coefficients-in-tx-log1-expx/308100#308100), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390866/recursion-relation-for-euler-numbers/390908#390908). Here is a formula for the $n$th derivative of the function $e^{\sin(x)}$

> $$\left( e^{\sin(x)}\right)^{(n)}={{ i}^{{n} }}\ e^{\sin ( x )} \sum _{k=0}^{n}  
> \sum _{j=0}^{n-k}\sum _{m = 0
> }^{k}  \frac{\left(-1 \right)^{n-k-m} {i}^{{ j + m}} }{{2}^{(j+m)}}  {n\choose k} \left\{\matrix{n-k\\j}\right\} \left\{\matrix{k\\m}\right\}  {\rm e}^{ i x (m - j)}\\  n \in \mathbb{N},\, i = \sqrt{-1}. $$

where $\left\{\matrix{n\\k}\right\}$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

**Note:** I'll appreciate if someone is interested in verifying this formula with Maple or Mathematica. I already tried it with Maple and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple application of [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

$$\partial_x^n e^{f(x)}=e^{f(x)}\sum \frac{n!}{\prod_{j=1}^n m_j!\,j!^{m_j}}\cdot \prod_{j=1}^nf^{(j)}(x)^{m_j},$$

where the sum is over all $n$-tuples $(m_1,\dots,m_n)\in{\Bbb N}^n$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^nj\,m_j=n$.