# The $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=\cosh g(x)$

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions, chain-rule

If we have a function

$$f(x)=\cosh\theta(x)$$

where we'll assume that $\theta$ is a sufficiently smooth function, then we can easily calculate its first few derivatives with respect to $x$, i.e.
$$f'(x)=\theta'(x)\sinh\theta(x),~f''(x)=\theta''(x)\sinh(x)+\theta'(x)^2\cosh\theta(x),$$
$$f'''(x)=\{\theta'''(x)+\theta(x)^3\}\sinh\theta(x)+3\theta'(x)\theta''(x)\cosh\theta(x),$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=(\theta''''+6\theta'\theta''^2)\sinh\theta+(4\theta'\theta'''+3\theta''^2+\theta^4)\cosh\theta,\dots$$

and so on.

Can we give the general term in the sequence for $f^{(n)}(x)$ in terms of $\theta$ and its derivatives?

Comment: Use $\cosh(x)=\frac 12(e^x+e^{-x})$ and this post which involves Bell polynomials  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441522/general-formula-or-a-pattern-for-the-nth-derivatives-of-efx

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [zwim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345526/the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-cosh-gx#comment6886397_3345526), one can compute this using the [General formula or a pattern for the $n$th derivatives of $e^{f(x)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441522/272831), or, more directly,

\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\cosh(g(x))&=\cosh(g(x))\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}B_{n,2k}\big(g'(x),\dots,g^{(n-2k+1)}(x)\big)\\&+\sinh(g(x))\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}B_{n,2k+1}\big(g'(x),\dots,g^{(n-2k)}(x)\big)\end{align}

using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).