# General formula for $n$-th derivative of $e^{f(x)}?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

> Question: Let $g(x) = e^{f(x)}$ where $f$ is infinitely differentiable function. 
>   Does there exist a formula for $n$-th derivative $g^{(n)}(x)$ where $n\geq 0?$

I obtain the following.

$$g'(x) = f'(x) e^{f(x)}$$
$$g''(x) = f''(x) e^{f(x)} + (f'(x))^2 e^{f(x)}$$
$$g'''(x) = f'''(x) e^{f(x)} + 3 f'(x) f''(x) e^{f(x)} + (f'(x))^3 e^{f(x)}.$$
But I could not obtain any pattern from above.

Comment: It looks like you would need another couple derivatives written out to start making generalizations.  It looks like there should be a "biased binomial expansion" in the coefficients, but the exact pattern isn't clear yet.

Comment: Massively related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441522/general-formula-or-a-pattern-for-the-nth-derivatives-of-efx/2810253

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397325/closed-form-for-nth-derivative-of-exponential-of-f

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Work with $$\ln(y)=f(x)$$ to get the higher derivative.

Comment: +1 - I like this idea of spotting patterns via implicit differentiation

Comment: I would like to understand the downvotes since I am not sure I get the hint right.

Comment: Hi, there is a closed formula on this paper :"On a Closed Formula for the Derivatives of
ef (x) and Related Financial Applications" written by Konstantinos Drakakis.
And i have invented a method to calculate it, if you want i can explain it to you.