# Taylor series expansion for $e^{\sin{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Given the function $$f(x)= e^{\sin{x}}$$ I have to write it without using the exponential or sine function.

I came to this point $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^k{x}}{k!}$$

How can I get rid of that $\sin^k(x)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put the taylor series for sin(x)

Comment: @user129901 that will get *very* messy though.

Comment: @Sabyasachi or else first do taylor expansion of sin(x) and then use taylor series of $e^x$ this looks like a nice product

Comment: @user129901 isn't it the same? What would be the difference between two methods?

Comment: @Simon both will give same series but taking an infinite series to some power is definitely less preferable than easily writing out the product for example $e ^{x-x^2}$ is $(1+x+x^2/2!..)$$(1-x^2+x^4/2!..)$

Comment: @Simon the final answer would be the same if you do it right, but using the Taylor series for $e^x$ first, will lead to a messy calculation.

Comment: See the formula in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397325/closed-form-for-nth-derivative-of-exponential-of-f).