# The series expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x}-1}}$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The function $ \displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x}-1}}$ doesn't have a Laurent series expansion at $x=0$.

But according to Wolfram Alpha, it does have a series expansion with terms raised to non-integer powers:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{x}-1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}- \frac{\sqrt{x}}{4} + \cdots$$

How is that series derived?

My initial thought was to use the general binomial theorem, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: What about finding the expansion of $y\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{y^2}-1}}$?

Comment: You can do it the "old" way, just take a couple of derivatives and plug in x=0 each time. It is a little work, but doable if you only need few terms

Comment: Because it doesn't have a Taylor series expansion at $x=0$.

Comment: Oof, that's just dumb, didn't even check that. But then a series can developed at a different value of x, but that may not be what you are asking...

Comment: I was looking specifically at $x=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Related problems:** [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413492/the-series-expansion-of-frac1-sqrtex-1-at-x-0), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327416/solve-the-sequence-u-n-1-fracu-1n-fracu-2n-1-ldots-frac/328401#328401). Just find the Taylor series of the function

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{e^{x}-1}}. $$

**Added:** Here is a formula for the $n$th derivative of the function

> $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{e^{x}-1}}\right)^{(n)}= \frac{\pi}{2}\sum _{k=0}^{n}  \sum _{i=0}^{k}  \sum _{m=0}^{i}{
> \frac { \binom {k}{i}\left[\matrix{i\\m}\right] \left\{\matrix{n\\k}\right\} 
> x^{\frac{1}{2}-m}\, {\rm e}^{(k-i) x}  \left( {\rm e}^x - 1
> \right)^{i-k-\frac{1}{2}}    }{\Gamma  \left( \frac{1}{
> 2}-k+i \right) \Gamma  \left( \frac{3}{2}-m \right) }} .$$

**Note:** I'll appreciate it if someone can verify this formula with Maple or Mathematica.

Comment: @RandomVariable: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Binomial expansion version... as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
e^x-1 = \left(1 + x +\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} +\dots\right) - 1 = x \left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{6}+\dots\right) = x(1+S),
$$
where $S \to 0$.  So
$$
\left(e^x-1\right)^{-1/2} = x^{-1/2}\left(1+S\right)^{-1/2}
= x^{-1/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k} S^k
$$
Then put in what $S$ is (as many terms as needed...)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&{1 \over \root{\expo{x} - 1}}
=
{1 \over \root{x}} + \pars{{1 \over \root{\expo{x} - 1}} - {1 \over \root{x}}}
=
{1 \over \root{x}}
- {\root{\expo{x} - 1} - \root{x} \over \root{x}\root{\expo{x} - 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over \root{x}}
-
{\pars{\expo{x} - 1} - x
\over \root{x}\root{\expo{x} - 1}\pars{\root{\expo{x} - 1} + \root{x}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over \root{x}}
-
{\expo{x} - 1 - x \over \root{x}\pars{\expo{x} - 1} + x\root{\expo{x} - 1}}
=
{1 \over \root{x}}
-
\root{x}\bracks{%
{\expo{x} - 1 - x \over x\pars{\expo{x} - 1} + x^{3/2}\root{\expo{x} - 1}}}
\end{align}

> Also,
> $$
> \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}
> {\expo{x} - 1 - x \over x\pars{\expo{x} - 1} + x^{3/2}\root{\expo{x} - 1}}
> =
> \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}
> {x^{2}/2 \over x\pars{x} + x^{3/2}\pars{x^{1/2}}} = {1 \over 4}
> $$

Then,
\begin{align}
&{1 \over \root{\expo{x} - 1}}
=
{1 \over \root{x}} - {1 \over 4}\,\root{x}
+
\root{x}\bracks{%
{1 \over 4}
-
{\expo{x} - 1 - x \over x\pars{\expo{x} - 1} + x^{3/2}\root{\expo{x} - 1}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over \root{x}} - {1 \over 4}\,\root{x}
+
x^{3/2}\
\underbrace{\bracks{%
{1 \over 4x}
-
{1 \over x^{2}}\,{\pars{\expo{x} - 1}/x - 1 \over \pars{\expo{x} - 1}/x + \root{\pars{\expo{x} - 1}/x}}}}
_{\ds{\to -\,{1 \over 12}\ \mbox{when}\ x \to 0^{+}}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#0000ff}{\large%
> {1 \over \root{\expo{x} - 1}}
> \sim {1 \over \root{x}} - {1 \over 4}\,\root{x} - {1 \over 12}\,x^{3/2}}
> $$

Answer (score 2):

At the site https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657078, it was derived that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to0}\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}\,\Biggr]^{(n)}
=-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k)!!} \sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\frac{s(n+m,m)}{\binom{n+m}{m}},\quad n\ge0,
\end{equation*}
where $s(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the first kind.
Hence, we have
\begin{align}
\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{x}{\operatorname{e}^x-1}}\,\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+u(x))}{u(x)}}\,\Biggr]^{(n)}, \quad u=u(x)=\operatorname{e}^x-1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}}\,\Biggr]^{(k)} B_{n,k}(\operatorname{e}^x,\operatorname{e}^x,\dotsc,\operatorname{e}^x)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}}\,\Biggr]^{(k)} \operatorname{e}^{kx} B_{n,k}(1,1,\dotsc,1)\\
&\to \sum_{k=0}^n\lim_{u\to0}\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}}\,\Biggr]^{(k)} S(n,k), \quad x\to0\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^n\Biggl[\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(2\ell-3)!!}{(2\ell)!!} \sum_{m=0}^\ell(-1)^m\binom{\ell}{m}\frac{s(k+m,m)}{\binom{k+m}{m}}\Biggr] S(n,k)
\end{align}
and
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{x}{\operatorname{e}^x-1}}\,
=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(2\ell-3)!!}{(2\ell)!!} \sum_{m=0}^\ell(-1)^m\binom{\ell}{m}\frac{s(k+m,m)}{\binom{k+m}{m}}\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}, \quad |x|<\pi,
\end{equation}
where $S(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind.
Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\operatorname{e}^x-1|}}\,
=-\frac1{\sqrt{|x|}\,}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^nS(n,k)\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(2\ell-3)!!}{(2\ell)!!} \sum_{m=0}^\ell(-1)^m\binom{\ell}{m}\frac{s(k+m,m)}{\binom{k+m}{m}}\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
for $0\ne|x|<\pi$.

References

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
2. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.