# About Rayleigh's formula

Tags: special-functions

How to use $\displaystyle j_n(x)=(-1)^nx^n\left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx}\right)^n \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$?

for example, to find $j_3(x)$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula you provided uses a compact way of writing operators.

For example, at $n = 2$, the term $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx}\right)^2$ should be understood to mean the operator
$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx}\right)^2=\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx}\frac1x \frac d{dx}.$$

You can see the values of Rayleigh's formula which are Spherical Bessel functions on the [*Wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions%3a_jn.2C_yn), but lets calculate some of them so you can get a feel for how this operator works.

We have (I am writing these as they are typically written - like on the Wiki page):

$$\displaystyle j_n(x)=(-1)^nx^n\left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx}\right)^n \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$$

So:

$\displaystyle j_0(x) = (-1)^0x^0\left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx}\right)^0 \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$

$\displaystyle j_1(x) = (-1)^1x^1\left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx}\right)^1 \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) = (-1)^1x^1\left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}\right) = \frac{\sin x}{x^2} - \frac{\cos x}{x}$

$\displaystyle j_2(x) = (-1)^2x^2\left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx}\right)^2 \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$

$\displaystyle = x^2 \left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx} \frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx}\right) \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$

$\displaystyle = x^2 \left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx} \frac{1} {x} \right) \left(\frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}\right)$

$\displaystyle = x^2 \left(\frac{1} {x} \frac{d} {dx} \right) \left(\frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^3}\right) $

$\displaystyle = x^2 \left(\frac{1} {x} \right) \left(\frac{(3-x^2) \sin x - 3x \cos x}{x^4}\right)$

$\displaystyle = \left(\frac{3}{x^2} -1 \right) \frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{3 \cos x}{x^2}$

$\displaystyle j_3(x) = (-1)^3x^3\left(\frac{1}{x} \frac{d} {dx}\right)^3 \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) = -x^3 \left(\frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx} \right)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right) $

After some calculations, we arrive at:

$$j_3(x) = \left(\frac{15}{x^3} - \frac{6}{x} \right) \frac{\sin x}{x} -\left(\frac{15}{x^2} - 1 \right) \frac{\cos x}{x}$$

I will let you work that last one, but if you get stuck, just reply and I will add the details!

Comment: Excellent! $+ 1$

Answer (score 3):

Related problem:[(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413492/the-series-expansion-of-frac1-sqrtex-1-at-x-0). You can use the **new identity** for Rayleigh's formula which computes the [spherical Bessel functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $ j_n(z) $ of the first kind

> $$ j_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{ n\brack k} {2}^{n-k}\sum _{s=0}^{k}  s! { k\brace s}\sum _{m=0}^{s}{\frac {\left( -1 \right)^{n+s-m}{x}^{-n-1+m}\sin \left( x+\frac{m\pi}{2} 
>  \right) }{   m! }}\quad n\in \mathbb{N} \cup {0}. $$

where $ n\brack k $ and $ n\brace k $ are [Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) of the first and second kind respectively.

For instance, for $n=3,4$, you get

> $$ -{\frac {-\cos \left( t \right) {t}^{3}+6\,\sin \left( t \right) {t}^{
> 2}+15\,\cos \left( t \right) t-15\,\sin \left( t \right) }{{t}^{4}}},$$
>
> $$ {\frac {\sin \left( t \right) {t}^{4}+10\,\cos \left( t \right) {t}^{3
> }-45\,\sin \left( t \right) {t}^{2}-105\,\cos \left( t \right) t+105\,
> \sin \left( t \right) }{{t}^{5}}}.$$

**Note:** I'll appreciate if someone double check the formula.

Comment: Well, your $n=3$ terms agrees with the one I calculated exactly. Not proof, but just thought I'd mention.

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks for doing that. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome and neat formula! +1 for nice formula! I used his formula, but it is nice that there are others out there and I found several ways to calculate these terms when searching, but that is a lovely formula. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: Thank you very much for the comment.