# Simplified form for $\frac{\operatorname d^n}{\operatorname dx^n}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)$?

Tags: derivatives, alternative-proof

I have found the following formula:
$$\frac{\operatorname  d^n}{\operatorname dx^n}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)=(-1)^n\,\frac{n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}e^{kx}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i}(k-i)^{n-1}+x\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}e^{kx}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^i\binom{n+1}{i}(k-i)^n}{\left(e^x-1\right)^{n+1}}.
$$
[My proof](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4Bs_2_T-WoAb2R0MnoyQ0pWYU0/) of this formula is complicated.
Can somebody find some simple proof?

Comment: What is your complicated proof? Does it take more than 2 pages? If you don't feel like writing it in $\LaTeX$ you can put it as an image.

Comment: My proof is natural, but has too many steps. It's via many recurrences, and prooving some complicated combinatorial identities.

Comment: Then maybe you find some of those identities online, link them, and put the rest of it in here. Or (assuming you have it on paper and a multifunction printer), put the images regarding all steps on a cloud service and the main steps here, along with the links. I didn't downvote (I ran out of votes), but I agree you have to show your steps and your effort.

Comment: Link to my proof: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Bs_2_T-WoAb2R0MnoyQ0pWYU0/edit?usp=sharing But, excuse me, my english is not so good.

Comment: Not so good? I've seen worse from native speakers. I suggested an edit to add the link to your post. That must have been a lot of work! I'll upvote as soon as I can.

Comment: I completely don't understand the downvotes. The question certainly shows effort, and is quite a natural one.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413492/the-series-expansion-of-frac1-sqrtex-1-at-x-0).

Comment: I upvoted the question.

Comment: @Feanor, initially, there was no link to that document.

Comment: Doesn't this come directly from the series in terms of Bernoulli numbers by definition? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generating_function.

Comment: Your “proof” needs permission to open.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a starting point.

Using the general Leibniz rule,

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x\right)\left(\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right).$$

Now, the "0-th" derivative of $x$ is $x$, and the 1st derivative of $x$ is $1$, and all 2nd and higher order derivatives vanish. Then, the only non-zero terms in the sum above are the k=0,1 terms, so we get:

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{x}{e^x-1} = \binom{n}{0}\left(\frac{d^0}{dx^0}x\right)\left(\frac{d^{n-0}}{dx^{n-0}}\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right)+\binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{d^1}{dx^1}x\right)\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right)\\
 = x\left(\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right) + n\left(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{1}{e^x-1}\right).$$

At the very least this should obviate the need for complicated products of summations as you currently have.

Comment: Did you not forget $\binom{n}{k}$ in the first equation?

Comment: @Sasha Thank you for catching that little gaffe, and shame on the people who upvoted me. $\binom{n}{0}=1$ doesn't change much, so it comes to missing factor of $\binom{n}{1}=n$ in the second term.

Answer (score 3):

i hope this would help you in some way
$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac{x}{\cos(ix)-i\sin (ix)-1}$$
$$=\frac{x}{-(1-\cos (ix))-\sin (ix)}$$
$$=\frac{x}{-2\sin^2(\frac{ix}{2})-\sin (ix)}$$
$$=\frac{x}{-2\sin (\frac{ix}{2})(\sin (\frac{ix}{2})+\cos (\frac{ix}{2}))}$$
$$=\frac{x}{-2\sin (\frac{ix}{2})e^{\frac{-x}{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{xe^{\frac{x}{2}}}{i\sinh (\frac{x}{2})}$$

Answer (score 2):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413492/the-series-expansion-of-frac1-sqrtex-1-at-x-0), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417039/about-rayleighs-formula/417177#417177). Here is a formula

> $$ \sum _{k=0}^{n}  \sum _{m=0}^{n-k} ( -1 )^{m} m! {n\choose k} {n-k \brace m}(2-k)_k\,\frac{{x}^{1-k}\,{\rm e}^{mx}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}-1 \right)^{m+1}}, $$

where $(a)_b$ is the [Pocchammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) and $ {n \brace k} $ is the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice formula. How did you derive it?

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor series of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ is well-known:

$$\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} x^k$$

$$\Longrightarrow \frac{\operatorname d^n}{\operatorname dx^n}\left(\frac{x}{e^x-1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{\operatorname d^n}{\operatorname dx^n}x^k$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} \frac{k!}{(k-n)!}x^{k-n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{B_k}{(k-n)!}x^{k-n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The formula
\begin{equation*}
\biggl(\frac{1}{\operatorname{e}^x-1}\biggr)^{(n)}
=(-1)^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(j-1)!S(n+1,j)\biggl(\frac1{\operatorname{e}^x-1}\biggr)^j
\end{equation*}
is perhaps useful. This formula is a consequence of the following

References

1. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Explicit formulae for computing Euler polynomials in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **272** (2014), 251--257; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2014.05.018.
2. Bai-Ni Guo and Feng Qi, *Some identities and an explicit formula for Bernoulli and Stirling numbers*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **255** (2014), 568--579; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.06.020.
3. C.-F. Wei and B.-N. Guo, *Complete monotonicity of functions connected with the exponential function and derivatives*, Abstr. Appl. Anal. **2014** (2014), Article ID 851213, 5 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1155/2014/851213.
4. A.-M. Xu and Z.-D. Cen, *Some identities involving exponential functions and Stirling numbers and applications*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **260** (2014), 201--207; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.09.077.