# show that $\int_0^x x^{-n} J_{n+1} (x)dx= \frac{1}{ 2^nn} -x^{-n} J_n (x)$

Tags: bessel-functions

[image]

how to prove that $$\int_0^x x^{-n} J_{n+1} (x)dx= \frac{1}{ 2^nn} -x^{-n} J_n (x).$$

Comment: (Not a huge fan of the double dipping of the variable $x$, incidentally, but I suppose that's not your fault.)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805379) is for spherical Bessel functions but it's essentially the same calculation; their upper limit is $\infty$, but that's not the important part.

Comment: Is $\underline{| n}$ in the scan really just $n$? I'm getting $n!$..?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Factorial - History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#History) on Wikipedia,

> Another later notation, in which the argument of the factorial was half-enclosed by the left and bottom sides of a box, was popular for some time in Britain and America but fell out of use, perhaps because it is difficult to typeset.

By way of saying: $\underline{| n}$ in the scan is not $n$, it is $n!$.

---

Indeed: from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Recurrence_relations) or [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6) (amongst others), we have the recurrence relation
$$
\frac{d}{d x} \Bigl( x^{-n} J_n(x) \Bigr) = -x^{-n} J_{n + 1}(x). 
$$

Integrating both sides of this from $0$ to $t$ we get
$$
\int_0^t x^{-n} J_{n + 1}(x) \, d x = -x^{-n} J_n(x) \biggr\rvert_{x = 0}^{x = t} = -t^{-n} J_n(t) + \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} x^{-n} J_n(x). 
$$
The remaining limit is (again by e.g. [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7#i))
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{-n} J_n(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{-n} \frac{x^n}{2^n} \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)} = \frac{1}{2^n \Gamma(n+1)} = \frac{1}{2^n n!} 
$$
for integers $n > 0$.