# Series expansion of $\sqrt{\log(1+x)}$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Mathematica gives the following series expansion of $\sqrt{\log(1+x)}$ at $x=0$.
$$
x^{1/2}-\frac{1}{4}x^{3/2}+\frac{13}{96}x^{5/2}-\cdots
$$
You can find it from Wolfram alpha too.

How can I obtain the expansion?
Obviously Taylor expansion is impossible because $\sqrt{\log(1+x)}$ is not analytic at $x=0$.
Taylor expansion of the $\log(1+x)$ at $x=1$ is possible. But I don't know how to take sequre root on the expanded series.
I think I have not learned about square root of a series from calculs or analysis course.
From what material can I study about such things?

Comment: At $x=0$. What does that mean?.

Comment: @boywholived, I can't understand your question. What is your point? The expansion is an asymptotic expansion for $\sqrt{\log(1+x)}$ when $x \to +0$.

Comment: Here is a [similar problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413492/the-series-expansion-of-frac1-sqrtex-1-at-x-0).

Comment: I hope you got the idea from the link I gave you which you consider the function $ \sqrt{x}\sqrt{\ln(1+x)} $.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal, yes I got how it works. But what is the motivation of the idea multiplying $\sqrt{x}$ at first? I'd like to know if there are some general rule or technic for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$
and recall that
$$(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)x^2}{2}+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)x^3}{3}+\cdots$$
so for $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$\sqrt{\log(1+x)}=\left(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}\left(1+(\underbrace{-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}+O(x^3))}_{=u}\right)^{1/2}\\=\sqrt{x}(1+\frac{1}{2}u-\frac{1}{8}u^2+O(u^3))=\sqrt{x}(1-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\frac{x^2}{4}+O(x^3))\\=\sqrt{x}(1-\frac{x}{4}+\frac{13x^2}{96}+O(x^3))$$

Answer (score 7):

$\log(1+x)$ is analytic at $x=0$, and its Taylor series is $x-x^2/2+x^3/3-...$
Take out the common factor $x(1-x/2+x^2/3-...)$
When you take the square-root, the first factor gives $x^{1/2}$ of course, and the second factor gives an ordinary Taylor series.  Do you need help finding its square root?

Comment: Yes, I need the help! I can't understand what "the second factor gives an ordinary Taylor series" means.

Comment: Try $\sqrt{1-x/2+x^2/3-...}=1+ax+bx^2+cx^3+...$  Square both sides $1-x/2+x^2/3-...=(1+ax+bx^2+cx^3+...)(1+ax+bx^2+cx^3+...)$  Expand the right-hand side, and equate coefficients.  You will find $a$ first, from the coefficients of $x$, then use that and the coefficients of $x^2$ to find $b$.

Comment: Then factoring $x$ out and making a constant term seem like a crucial step to use this method of taking the square root. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$g(x):={\log(1+x)\over x}=1-{1\over2} x+{1\over3}x^2-\ldots$$
has a removable singularity at $0$ and takes the value $1$ there. It follows that in some neighborhood $U$ of $0$ the function $g$ has an analytic square root $f$ with $f(0)=1$, and that we may write
$$\sqrt{\log(1+x)}=\sqrt{\mathstrut x}\  f(x)\qquad (x\in U)\ ,\tag{1}$$
where now the  ambiguity in the given expression resides in the factor $\sqrt{\mathstrut x}$. The function
$$f(x)=\sum_{k\geq0} a_k x^k,\quad a_0=1,$$
 satisfies
$$x\>\bigl(f(x)\big)^2=\log(1+x)\qquad(x\in U)\ ,$$
or
$$\sum_{r\geq0}\left(\sum_{k+l=r} a_k a_l\right) x^{r+1}=\sum_{r\geq0}{(-1)^r\over r+1}x^{r+1}\qquad(x\in U)\ .$$
This implies
$$2a_0a_r +\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} a_k a_{r-k} ={(-1)^r\over r+1}\qquad(r\geq1)\ ,$$
from which we obtain the following recursion formula for the coefficients $a_r\ $:
$$a_r={1\over2}\left({(-1)^r\over r+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} a_k a_{r-k}\right)\qquad(r\geq1)\ .$$
Plugging the first few $a_r$ into $(1)$ we therefore have
$$\sqrt{\log(1+x)}=\sqrt{\mathstrut x}\ \left(1-{1\over4}x+{13\over96} x^2-{35\over 384}x^3+{6271\over 92\,160} x^4-\ldots\right)\quad.$$

Comment: What is your motivation of factoring out $\sqrt{x}$ at first? And how could you sure $f(x)$ would be analytic before completing the rest of the process by finding $a_i$?

Comment: @asofas: See my edit.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the kindly explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(1+x)}\,$ for $x>0$. Then, by virtue of Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials,
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_k[\ln(1+x)]^{1/2-k} B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{0!}{1+x},-\frac{1!}{(1+x)^2},\dotsc,(-1)^{n-k}\frac{(n-k)!}{(1+x)^{n-k+1}}\biggr)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_k[\ln(1+x)]^{1/2-k}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(1+x)^n} B_{n,k}(0!,1!,\dotsc,(n-k)!)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_k[\ln(1+x)]^{1/2-k}\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(1+x)^n} (-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\ln(1+x)}\,}{(1+x)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k}s(n,k)\frac{1}{[\ln(1+x)]^{k}},
\end{align*}
where $s(n,k)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the first kind. Utilizing this general formula for the $n$th derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(1+x)}\,$, one can derive Taylor series expansion of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{\ln(1+x)}\,$ around any point $x_0>0$.

References

1. L. Comtet, *Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions*, Revised and Enlarged Edition, D. Reidel Publishing Co., 1974; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-2196-8.
2. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Answer (score 1):

This series expansion can be evaluated by first writing
$$
\log^{1/2}(1+x)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k\right)^{1/2}=\sqrt x\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}x^k\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Applying the well-known expansion for [powers of power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_raised_to_powers) we obtain
$$
\log^{1/2}(1+x)=\sqrt x\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_m x^m,
$$
where $c_0=1$ and
$$
c_m=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^m(k/2-m+k)\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}c_{m-k}.
$$
This series converges on $x\in[0,1)$ and is implemented in Mathematica as

```
c[0] := 1;
c[m_] := 1/m Sum[(k/2 - m + k) (-1)^k/(k + 1) c[m - k], {k, 1, m}];
g[x_, M_] := Sqrt[x] Sum[c[m] x^m, {m, 0, M}];
```

Here is a plot of $\log^{1/2}(1+x)$ compared to the truncated series expansion for $M=1$ and $M=6$:

[image]

Finally, here is a list of the first several coefficients $c_m$:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m & c_m \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & -\frac{1}{4} \\
 2 & \frac{13}{96} \\
 3 & -\frac{35}{384} \\
 4 & \frac{6271}{92160} \\
 5 & -\frac{2211}{40960} \\
 6 & \frac{2760011}{61931520} \\
 7 & -\frac{1875133}{49545216} \\
 8 & \frac{557576779}{16986931200} \\
 9 & -\frac{13761972821}{475634073600} \\
 10 & \frac{3244313727791}{125567395430400} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k+1}, \quad |x|<1.
\end{equation}
This means that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to0}\biggl[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\biggr]^{(k)}
=(-1)^k\frac{k!}{k+1}, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}
By virtue of the Faa di Bruno formula, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\Biggl[\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}\,\Biggr]^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_k \biggl[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\biggr]^{1/2-k} B_{n,k}\Biggl(\biggl[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\biggr]', \biggl[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\biggr]'', \dotsc, \biggl[\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\biggr]^{(n-k+1)}\Biggr)\\
&\to\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle\frac12\biggr\rangle_k B_{n,k}\biggl(-\frac{1!}{2}, \frac{2!}{3}, \dotsc, (-1)^{n-k+1}\frac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+2}\biggr), \quad x\to0\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k} B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{1!}{2}, \frac{2!}{3}, \dotsc, \frac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+2}\biggr)\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(2k-3)!!}{2^k} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\frac{s(n+m,m)}{\binom{n+m}{m}}\\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k)!!} \sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\frac{s(n+m,m)}{\binom{n+m}{m}},
\end{align*}
where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-Stir1st=eq}
B_{n,k}\biggl(\frac{1!}2,\frac{2!}3,\dotsc,\frac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+2}\biggr)
=\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\frac{s(n+m,m)}{\binom{n+m}{m}}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}\,=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k)!!} \sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\frac{s(n+m,m)}{\binom{n+m}{m}}\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{|\ln(1+x)|}\,=-\sqrt{|x|}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2k-3)!!}{(2k)!!} \sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^m\binom{k}{m}\frac{s(n+m,m)}{\binom{n+m}{m}}\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{equation}

References

1. Feng Qi and Aying Wan, *A closed-form expression of a remarkable sequence of polynomials originating from a family of entire functions connecting the Bessel and Lambert functions*, Sao Paulo Journal of Mathematical Sciences **16** (2022), no. 2, 1238--1248; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s40863-021-00235-2.
2. F. Qi, *Diagonal recurrence relations for the Stirling numbers of the first kind*, Contrib. Discrete Math. **11** (2016), no. 1, 22--30; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v11i1.62389.
3. F. Qi, *Explicit formulas for computing Bernoulli numbers of the second kind and Stirling numbers of the first kind*, Filomat **28** (2014), no. 2, 319--327; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/FIL1402319O.
4. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *A diagonal recurrence relation for the Stirling numbers of the first kind*, Appl. Anal. Discrete Math. **12** (2018), no. 1, 153--165; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM170405004Q.
5. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.