# Question about Euler numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that

[image]

where $\ E_{2n}$ is the $2n^{th}$ [euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number)

and $$\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{E_n}{n!}x^n$$

Is there maybe some link with an answer, or a book in which the above is shown?

---

Comment: :whats  source  ?

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo in the same link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number)

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390866/recursion-relation-for-euler-numbers/390908#390908).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal:if you can give me an answer because from 4 month to now and I didnt find way to solve the question

Answer (score 1):

We have $\cosh (x) \cdot \frac{1}{\cosh (x)} = 1$ and $\cosh (x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2k!}x^{2k}$. [Multiplying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division) and taking the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ we arrive at $E_0 = 1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2k!}\cdot\frac{E_{2n-2k}}{(2n-2k)!} = 0$ for $n \geq 1$. From here on this is a straight forward proof by induction.