# Closed form of even indexed Euler Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, determinant

Prove that:
$${\rm{E}}_{2n}=(-1)^n(2n)!\left|{\begin{array}{ccccccc} \frac{1}{2!} & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \\ \frac{1}{4!} & \frac{1}{2!} & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \\ \frac{1}{6!} & \frac{1}{4!} & \frac{1}{2!} & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\ \\ \frac{1}{(2n-2)!} & \frac{1}{(2n-4)!} & \frac{1}{(2n-6)!} & \frac{1}{(2n-8)!} & \cdots & \frac{1}{2!} & 1\\\\ \frac{1}{(2n)!} &\frac{1}{(2n-2)!} & \frac{1}{(2n-4)!} & \frac{1}{(2n-6)!} & \cdots & \frac{1}{4!} & \frac{1}{2!}\end{array}}\right|$$

where ${\rm E}_{2n}$ are the Euler numbers with even index. (given also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number )

---

I started the problem using the fact that: 
$$\sec x =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n {\rm E}_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}, \;\;\; \left | x \right |<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Hence:
$$\sec x \cdot \cos x =1 \implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n{\rm E}_{2n}x^{2n}}{\left ( 2n \right )!}\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1$$

Now I have to count , closely, in order to get what I want. Now I got stuck.. How can I proceed further? I cannot seem to combine the final result to get I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By expanding these determinants with the Laplace rule, you can simply check that they satisfy the same recursion satisfied by the Euler numbers, and that the identity holds for $n=0$ and $n=1$.

See also [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390866/recursion-relation-for-euler-numbers) (line $(2)$ in [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn)'s answer).

Comment: I got to (if I did the calculations right) :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left ( \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n}{2k}{\rm E}_{2n} \right )\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Equating coefficients I get that ${\rm E}_0=1$ and $\displaystyle {\rm E}_{2n}=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2k}{\rm E}_{2k} $. How can I proceed to get that det?

Comment: You mean expanding the det and find the recursive formula of the det?

Comment: @Tolaso: yes, exactly. Expand it with respect to the last column.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not that good at doing that, but I'll give it a try... there.

Comment: I tried expanding the det but unsuccessfully. What I have also tried was to use induction... but I get stuck. Could you show me the way for the det?