# The even-numbered coefficients of the Maclaurin series of $ \frac{1}{\cos(x)} $ are odd integers.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

Let’s consider $ G(z) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \dfrac{1}{\cos(z)} $ as the exponential generating function of the sequence of Euler numbers. How can one prove that in the Maclaurin series of $ G $,
$$
G(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_{2 k} \cdot \frac{z^{2 k}}{(2 k)!},
$$
the coefficients $ a_{2 k} $ are all odd integers?

For instance, it’s reasonable to use the fact that
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}: \quad
a_{2 n} = \frac{{G^{(2 n)}}(0)}{(2 n)!},
$$
but this way of bringing it into life seems too much complicated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean the power series has even powers.

Comment: Consider taking the product with $\cos(z)$ and using induction?

Comment: **Hint:** What is the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of $\cos z$ ?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390866/recursion-relation-for-euler-numbers/390908#390908).

Comment: The OP seems to be asking why the non-zero coefficients (associated to the even powers) are odd integers.

Comment: Arteom, your post is now much clearer, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand my comment into a solution: consider the (formal) product $1=\cos(z)\cdot\frac1{\cos(z)}$.  Expanding this out (using the already-established fact that $\frac1{\cos(z)}$ is even) and comparing powers of $x^2$, we get $a_0=1$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{a_{2i}}{(2i)!}\dfrac{(-1)^i}{(2n-2i)!}=0$; multiplying the latter by $(2n)!$ gives $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^ia_{2i}{2n\choose 2i}=0$.  But we already know that $a_0=1$, and since ${2n\choose 2i}={2n\choose2n-2i}$, all of the terms for $i\in\{1\ldots n-1\}$ pair off (by induction, using the fact that $a_{2i}$ is odd for $i\lt n$) to give even values.  (The exception is the middle value when $n$ is even; but in this case, $2n\choose n$ is even, by well-established properties of the binomial coefficents — see, e.g., [Kummer's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem).)  This thus implies that $a_{2n}$ must be odd.

Comment: Hi Steven. How do you ensure that the $ a_{2 i} $’s are integers in the first place?

Comment: @BerrickFillmore In fact, the recurrence relation for the $a_i$ given here establishes inductively that all the terms are integers (since we can write $(-1)^na_{2n}$ as a sum of integer multiples of integers).

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that. Thanks! +1 :)

Comment: Since your reasoning is concise and complete, no further information from my side is necessary. +1 of course

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I just posted my answer and I have to leave for a while. I just saw your answer and it looks as if my answer may be the same. If so, I should probably remove my answer. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: @robjohn Sorry for being so late in getting back to you - your answer stands just fine, I think. I was considering adding some of the detail to mine, particularly expanding out the recurrence relation and doing the quick odd/even case analysis; it's been long enough at this point that I think the answer will be all right as it is, though, particularly with yours for deeper details.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full solution, but I hope that it might help you in some way.

There is a nice characterization of the Maclaurin series of $ \sec $ by the Frenchman Désiré André, which he discovered while studying [Bertrand’s Ballot Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).

Define a sequence $ (A_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ of natural numbers by
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \quad
A_{n} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\text{The number of alternating permutations of $ \{ 1,\ldots,n \} $}.
$$
An alternating permutation of $ \{ 1,\ldots,n \} $ is simply a permutation $ \sigma $ of $ \{ 1,\ldots,n \} $ satisfying
$$
\sigma(1) > \sigma(2) < \sigma(3) > \ldots.
$$
André [showed](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/16.pdf) that
$$
\forall x \in \left( - \frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right): \quad
\sec(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} A_{2 n} \cdot \frac{x^{2 n}}{(2 n)!},
$$
where $ A_{0} \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} 1 $.

Hence, your problem boils down to showing that $ A_{2 n} \equiv 1 ~ (\text{mod} ~ 2) $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}_{0} $. This is as far as I can go.

Comment: Well, thanks, suppose that i'll be able to try getting something from the notion of alternating permutations, at least this way looks the most reasonable one.

Comment: As a start, you can read the [Wikipedia article on alternating numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation).

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** We know, that $\cos$ is an *even* function, i.e. $\cos(z)=\cos(-z)$ and the powers of $z$ with non-zero coefficients of the power series representation of $\cos$ are *even*.

\begin{align*}
\cos(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}
\end{align*}

> Let's consider $f(z)=\frac{1}{\cos(z)}$. Since $\cos$ is *even* we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{1}{\cos (z)}=\frac{1}{\cos (-z)}=f(-z)
> \end{align*}
>   So, $f(z)$ is also an even function and we get the representation
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{z^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{(-z)^{n}}{n!}=f(-z)
> \end{align*}
>
> Comparing coefficients of $z^n$ implies that $a_{2n+1}=0$ for $n\geq 0$ and we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}
> \end{align*}

Comment: As i can see from your solution, you've shown that all the coefficients $a_{2n+1}=0$, but how can i derive from it that all the $a_{2n} \equiv 1 (mod2)$?
\\
Upd: I'm sorry for making everybody confused, the text of the problem was corrected a bit.

Comment: @Arteom: According to your previous formulation I had the impression you wanted to show that the *function* is even.  To show that the coefficients $a_{2n}$ are *odd* is a different story. I will think about it. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Now that I've had a chance to read Steven Stadnicki's answer, I see that my answer below is essentially the same, with some added detail.

Since $\frac1{\cos(x)}$ is even, all the odd order terms are $0$. So we will look only at the even order terms. Since
$$
1=\overbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_{2k}}{(2k)!}x^{2k}}^{1/\cos(x)}\overbrace{\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^j}{(2j)!}x^{2j}}^{\cos(x)}\tag{1}
$$
we have that $a_0=1$, and for $k\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=(2k)!\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\frac{a_{2j}}{(2j)!(2k-2j)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{2k}{2j}a_{2j}\\
&=(-1)^ka_0+a_{2k}+\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{2k}{2j}a_{2j}\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\small\displaystyle(-1)^k+a_{2k}+\sum_{j=1}^{(k-1)/2}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{2k}{2j}(a_{2j}-a_{2k-2j})&\text{if $k$ is odd}\\
\small\displaystyle(-1)^k+a_{2k}+\sum_{j=1}^{(k-2)/2}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{2k}{2j}(a_{2j}+a_{2k-2j})+\binom{2k}{k}a_k&\text{if $k$ is even}
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Now we proceed inductively. Assume that for all $j\lt k$, $a_{2j}$ is odd.

If $k$ is odd, then each term of the sum in $(2)$ is even since the difference of two odds is even.

If $k$ is even, then each term of the sum in $(2)$ is even since the sum of two odds is even. For $k\gt0$, $\binom{2k}{k}=2(k-1)\binom{2k-2}{k-1}$ is even.

Therefore, whether $k$ is even or odd, we have that $(-1)^k+a_{2k}$ is even. Thus, $a_{2k}$ is odd.