# $n$th derivative of $\tanh$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

Successive derivative of $\tanh u$ can be expressed as polynomial functions of $\tanh u$:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{du}\tanh u&=1-\tanh^2u\\
\frac{d^2}{du^2}\tanh u&=-2\tanh u\left(1-\tanh^2u\right)\\
\frac{d^3}{du^3}\tanh u&=2\left(1-\tanh^2u\right)\left(3\tanh^2u-1\right)\\
\frac{d^4}{du^4}\tanh u&=-8\tanh u\left(1-\tanh^2u\right)\left(3\tanh^2u-2\right)\\
\ldots
\end{align}
I am specially interested in the derivatives of even order. Their expressions can be found in [this article](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/45-4/quartboyadzhiev04_2007.pdf) by Boyadzhiev:
Denoting $z=\tanh u$ and $C_{2n}\left( \tanh u \right)=\tfrac{d^{2n}}{du^{2n}}\left( \tanh u \right) $,
\begin{equation}
C_{2n}\left(z \right)=2^{2n}\left( 1+ z\right)\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{k!}{2^k}S\left( 2n,k \right)\left( z-1 \right)^k
\end{equation} 
where $S(n,k)$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). We have also
$C_{2n}(0)=C_{2n}(\pm1)=0$. As $\tanh u$ is an odd function of $u$, they can also be expressed as
\begin{equation}
C_{2n}\left(z \right)=z\left( 1-z^2 \right)Q_{2n-2}(z^2) \tag{A}\label{eqA}
\end{equation} 
for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then, $Q_0(z)=-2$, $Q_2(z)=-8\left( 3z^2-2 \right)$... 
One may establish the recurrence relation (with $Z=z^2
$):
\begin{equation}
Q_{2n}=4Z\left( 1-Z \right)^2Q''_{2n-2}-6\left( 1-Z \right)\left( 3Z-1 \right)Q'_{2n-2}+4\left( 3Z-2 \right)Q_{2n-2}
\end{equation} 
What else can be found about the family $Q_{2n}$? Are they related to  a well-known family of polynomials?

Context:
Answering a [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291426/two-integral-representations-for-zeta3-from-zurabs-integral-and-standard-f/291442#291442), an integral representation for $\zeta(3)$ appeared:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{u-\tanh u}{u^3}\,du=\frac{7}{\pi^2}\zeta(3)
\end{equation} 
It can easily be checked using the residue theorem, taking advantage of the parity of the integrand. This result can be generalized for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ as:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{T_{2n-1}(u)-\tanh u}{u^{2n+1}}\,du=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2^{2n+1}-1}{\pi^{2n}}\zeta(2n+1)
\end{equation} 
where $T_{2n-1}(u)$ is the odd polynomial identical to the Maclaurin expansion for $\tanh u$:
\begin{equation}
\tanh u=u-\frac{1}{3}u^3+\frac{2}{15}u^5-\frac{17}{315}u^7+\ldots
\end{equation} 
up to the $u^{2n-1}$ term. This identity can also be checked using the residue theorem.

Now, integrating $2n$ times by parts, one obtains the following representation
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty C_{2n}\left(\tanh u  \right)\frac{du}{u}=(-1)^{n}\frac{2^{2n+1}-1}{\pi^{2n}}\left( 2n \right)!\zeta(2n+1)
\end{equation} 
With the representation \eqref{eqA} and the substitution $u=e^{-2v}$, one obtains
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \frac{v-1}{\left( v+ 1\right)^3}Q_{2n-2}\left( \left( \frac{1-v}{1+v} \right)^2 \right)\frac{dv}{\ln v}=(-1)^{n}\frac{2^{2n+1}-1}{4\pi^{2n}}\left( 2n \right)!\zeta(2n+1)
\end{equation} 
which provides another integral representation for $\zeta(2n+1)$.

Comment: See this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/what-is-the-formula-for-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x-arctan-x-sec-x-and-tan-x). I gave general techniques for the nth derivative of more general classes of functions.

Comment: By the way I published this kind of work in 2002 and in 2004 !!

Comment: See my [formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390866/recursion-relation-for-euler-numbers/390908#390908).

Comment: Thanks @Mhenni Benghorbal for the links about the successive derivatives. The question was about the possible determination of additional characteristics of the $Q_{2p}$ polynomials. Do you think we can find something?

Comment: The generating function for the polynomials  $Q_{2n-2}$ can be evaluated from the expression$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\tanh\left( u+x \right)+\tanh\left( u-x \right)\right]-\tanh u=
\frac{\tanh u\left( 1-\tanh^2u \right)}{\tanh^2u-\coth^2x}$$we find$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}Q_{2n-2}\left( \tanh u \right)=\frac{1}{\tanh^2u-\coth^2x}$$

Comment: Simplier: $$\frac{\partial ^n\tanh (x)}{\partial x^n}=(-1)^n 2^{1+n} \text{Li}_{-n}\left(-e^{-2 x}\right)$$ where: $\text{Li}_{-n}$ is  polylogarithm function.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk nice remark!

Answer (score 1):

**Derivative polynomial of the hyperbolic tangent function**

It is known that
$$
\tan z=\operatorname{i}\tanh(\operatorname{i}z).
$$
So, from the derivative polynomial of the tangent function $\tan z$, we can derive the derivative polynomial of the hyperbolic tangent function $\tanh z$.

It is not difficult to see that if $f$ is a function whose derivative is a polynomial in $f$, that is, $f'(x)=P_1(f(x))$ for some polynomial $P_1$, then all the higher order derivatives of $f$ are also polynomials in $f$, so we have a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ defined by $f^{(n)}(x)=P_n(f(x))$ for $n\ge0$. As usual, we call $P_n(u)$ the derivative polynomials of $f$. In fact, the polynomials $P_n$ are determined by
\begin{equation*}
P_0(u)=u, \quad P_{n+1}(u)=P'_n(u)P_1(u), \quad n\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation*}

**Theorem.**
*For $n\ge0$, the derivative polynomials $P_n(u)$ of the tangent function $u=\tan x$ can be explicitly computed by
\begin{equation}\label{Tan-Deriv-Polyn-Eq}
P_n(u)=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac12\bigl[n+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}\bigr]}a_{n,n+1-2k}u^{n+1-2k}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}\label{Tan-No-Exp-Form}
a_{2m-1,0}=(-1)^{m} \sum_{\ell=1}^{2m} (-1)^{\ell} 2^{2m-\ell} (\ell-1)! S(2m,\ell)
\end{equation}
for $m\ge1$ and
\begin{equation*}
a_{n,n+1-2k}=(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{\ell=n+1-2k}^{n+1} (-1)^{n-\ell} 2^{n+1-\ell} (\ell-1)! \binom{\ell}{n+1-2k} S(n+1,\ell)
\end{equation*}
for $0\le k\le\frac{1}{2}\bigl[n-\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}\bigr]$, where $S(n,k)$ for $n\ge k\ge1$ stand for the Stirling numbers of the second kind which can be analytically generated by
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(\operatorname{e}^x-1)^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty S(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}, \quad k\in\mathbb{N}.
\end{equation*}*

References

1. K. N. Boyadzhiev, *Derivative polynomials for tanh, tan, sech and sec in explicit form*, Fibonacci Quart. **45** (2007), no. 4, 291--303 (2008); available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0117.
2. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *An explicit formula for derivative polynomials of the tangent function*, Acta Universitatis Sapientiae Mathematica **9** (2017), no. 2, 348--359; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/ausm-2017-0026.