# Showing Taylor Series for $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ converges to $f$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Show Taylor Series for $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ converges to $f$

I am stuck because when taking the (n+1) th derivative of f, I do not see a general pattern. Meaning I am having difficulty in bounding $|f^{n+1}(x)|$

Comment: The Taylor series for $e^{-x^2}$ is exactly what you get when you plug $z = -x^2$ into the taylor series for $e^z$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The OP doesn't want the Taylor Series, S/he wamt to prove that it converges. S/he wants the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative as a function of $x$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2

Comment: Please look at my answer

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to use the fact that the composition of two real analytic functions is real analytic, and that $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=-x^2$ are real analytic.

Answer (score 1):

The series $e^x$ can be represented as:

$$ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
To find $e^{-x^2}$ we substitute $-x^2$ for $x$:

$$ e^{-x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}$$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}$$

We can conduct the root test to determine convergence:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n!}\right|^{1/n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x^{2}}{(n!)^{1/n}}\right|$$
$$= 0 < 1$$

Therefore, by the root test, the series absolutely converges.

Comment: Does simply proving convergence of the associated Taylor series prove that it convergent to it's associated function?

Comment: I mean how does this show that the Taylor series for y=e^-x^2 converges to e^-x^2?

Comment: I thought you were looking to understand how the series converges

Comment: Well I state in the question title taylor series converges to f