# Strange claim by WA involving nth derivative

Tags: derivatives, pochhammer-symbol

Playing a bit around with WA i found [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth%20derivative%20of%20%28x%2Ff%28x%29%29%5E%28n%2B1%29)

Namely:

$$\frac {d^n}{d^nx} \left(\frac x{f(x)}\right)^{n+1}=x\left(\frac 1{f(x)}\right)^{n+1}(2)_n$$
For $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$ and $n+1\ne x$ and $x \ne 0$ and $x\ne\frac1{f(x)}$

Where $(a)_n$ is the [pochhammer symbol.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol)

It seems very weird to me that the n'th derivative could be expressed so simply.

Is this correct, and if so how could it be proven?

Comment: If I am not wrong, with the definition of the Pochhammer symbol given in your link, if $n\geq 3$, $(2)_n=2(2-1)(2-2)...=0$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There's something goofy with the WA evaluation you link to. Suppose we take the case of $n=2$ explicitly; the resulting [evaluation](http://po.st/rwsQQx) is much more complicated than the form it spits out in your link. I think what it's doing is treating $f(x)$ like a constant; compare what WA [reports](http://po.st/ggjQsj) if you take $f(x)=1$.

Comment: @lhf I have updated my question with a question

Comment: WA apparently doesn't claim that this is the ordinary derivative, but rather the "symbolic integer derivative", whatever on earth that is... Here's a similar weird result (which, by the way, was the *single* hit that I got from Google when searching for that phrase in quotes), with $x^x$ instead: [link](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n-th+derivative+of+x^x).

Comment: ...or maybe that *is* the $n$th derivative of $x^x$?!?

Comment: I think the problem is related to me using a general $f(x)$ or the fact that $n$ also appeared in the function taking the derivative.

Comment: Try $ \left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)^{(n)} $. Check [related problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2/193914#193914).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing this instead

```
D[x/f[x],{x,n}]
```

returns itself, unevaluated.  For specific values of $n$, say $n = 3$, we get

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bx%2Ff%5Bx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C3%7D%5D&asynchronous=false

so we know that the above syntax is performing the differentiation as it is intended.  My experience with Wolfram|Alpha is that if you can enter an input in the Wolfram language, it is better to do so, because natural language input can be ambiguous.