# About the Binomial Transform of Incomplete Bell Polynomials $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j} B_{m,j}$?

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, bell-numbers

> The [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) is the shift operator for the Bell numbers. That is,
>   $$    \sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} B_j =B_{k+1} $$
>   where the $B_n$ are the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Is there a somewhat similar expressions involving incomplete Bell polynomials:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j} {\hat B}_{m,j}(x_1,x_2,...,x_{m-j+1})=\;?
$$

Maybe the definition of incomplete Bell polynomials helps to find an answer:
$$
{\hat B}_{m,j}(x_1,x_2,...,x_{m-j+1})=\sum_{{k_0+k_1+\cdots+k_N=j}\atop{k_1+2k_2+\cdots+Nk_N=m}}\binom{j}{k_0,k_1,\ldots,k_N}
\prod_{i=1}^Nx_i^{k_i}
$$

Comment: The incomplete Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1})$ become Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n,k)$ if we put all $x_i=1$. Therefore the Bell numbers come from the *complete* Bell polynomials by putting all $x_i=1$. The shift formula for Bell numbers is thus more directly related to the formula $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}B_{n-i}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-i})x_{i+1}=B_{n+1}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1})$$ for complete Bell polynomials, see the [wiki link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) for all the details.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We could look at the situation with the help of exponential generating functions.

The following holds: If $$A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \frac{z^k}{k!}$$ is an exponential generating function of the sequence $(a_k)$, then
\begin{align*}
A(z)e^z=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j} a_j \right)\frac{z^k}{k!}
\end{align*}
and applying the differential operator $D_z=\frac{d}{dz}$  we obtain
\begin{align*}
D_z A(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+1}\frac{z^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

> Since the exponential generating function of the *[Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Generating_function)* is
> \begin{align*}
> B(z)=\exp\left({e^z-1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}
> \end{align*}
> the relation
> \begin{align*}
> \ \qquad\qquad\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}B_j=B_{k+1}\qquad\qquad k\geq 0
> \end{align*}
> translates into
> \begin{align*}
> B(z)e^z&=D_z B(z)\\
> \end{align*}

We could now try to find an exponential generating function $P(z)$ for the *[partial ordinary Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Ordinary_Bell_polynomials)*. The expression
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}\hat{B}_{m,j}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,m-j+1)
\end{align*}
looks like the coefficient of
\begin{align*}
(-1)^{k-1}P(z)e^{-z}
\end{align*}
We could now check if this series could also be represented using operators like $D_z, e^z$, etc. Here we use the notation $\hat{B}_{m,j}$ in accordance with the Wiki page.

> **[Add-on 2017-04-30]** Some information regarding *ordinary* generating functions of *[partial ordinary Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Ordinary_Bell_polynomials)*. We use the *[coefficient of](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[t^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^n$ of a series $A(t)$.

> According to the referred Wiki page are the *partial ordinary Bell polynomials*
> \begin{align*}
> \hat{B}_{m,j}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{m-j+1})
> \end{align*}

> the coefficients of a bivariate generating function $\hat{\Phi}(t,u)$ with

> \begin{align*}
> \hat{\Phi}(t,u)&=\exp\left(u\sum_{l=1}^\infty x_lt^l\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{l=1}^\infty x_lt^l\right)^k\frac{u^k}{k!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=k}^\infty\hat{B}_{n,k}\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1}\right)t^n\right)\frac{u^k}{k!}
> \end{align*}

> We can write
> \begin{align*}
> \hat{B}_{m,j}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{m-j+1})&=[t^mu^j]\hat{\Phi}(t,u)\\
> &=[t^m]\underbrace{\left(\sum_{l=1}^\infty x_lt^l\right)^j}_{:= \hat{B}_j(t)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We recall the Euler transformation formula of a series
\begin{align*}
A(t)=\sum_{n=  0}^\infty a_nt^n\qquad\qquad 
\frac{1}{1-t}A\left(\frac{-t}{1-t}\right)=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}(-1)^ja_j\right)t^n\tag{2}
\end{align*}
This transformation formula together with a proof can be found e.g.  in [Harmonic Number Identities Via Euler's transform](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Boyadzhiev/boyadzhiev3.pdf) by K.N. Boyadzhiev. See remark 2 with $\lambda=1, \mu=-1$.

> We conclude according to (1) and (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^{j}\binom{m}{j}\hat{B}_{m,j}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{m-j+1})
> &=[t^mu^j]\frac{1}{1-t}\hat{\Phi}\left(\frac{-t}{1-t},u\right)\\
> &=[t^m]\frac{1}{1-t}\hat{B}_j\left(\frac{-t}{1-t}\right)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** Regrettably there seems to be no simple representation of the coefficients in (3) based on the ordinary generating function. An exponential generating function
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=k}^\infty\hat{B}_{n,k}\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
of the partial ordinary Bell polynomials is not stated at the Wiki-page about Bell polynomials and useful represenations are not known to me.

Comment: ok, I think I start to see what you mean. I also checked the wiki page again and found $\Phi (t,u)=\exp \left(u\sum _{r=1}^{\infty }x_{r}{\frac {t^{r}}{r!}}\right)=\sum _{n,k\geq 0}B_{n,k}(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n-k+1}){\frac {t^{n}}{n!}}u^{k}$. Putting your suggestions this becomes $\Phi (t,u)e^{-t}=\sum _{n,k\geq 0}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom{k}{j}B_{n,j}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\right)u^{k}{\frac {t^{n}}{n!}}$, where I'm not sure if I've chosen the correct variable $t$ or $u$...

Comment: You mean using this: $\frac{1}{1-z}A\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}a_j\right)z^n$?  But where do the $x_k$'s come from then? And $m$ looks like a free parameter so it should be $A_m(z)$ then right?

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. Cheers,

Comment: My comment on the summation was crap. I deleted it. You also deleted one. May I ask why?

Comment: @draks...: I sometimes remove comments which are outdated and do not have useful information any longer. Did you make some progress?

Comment: I have to compile the hints, I found on here and there. It doesn't look like a result right away, but I'm optimistic...

Comment: @draks...: I've added some info to clarify aspects about ordinary and exponential generating functions, regrettably without substantial information regarding a nice formula.

Comment: Be careful to note the difference between the Euler transformation of an o.g.f. and an e.g.f.

Comment: @TomCopeland: I typically apply Euler's transformation formula to an ogf as indicated in (2). Anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, nope. Just made the comment so others would not be confused and become aware of a difference. Both forms are rather important.

Comment: @TomCopeland: I agree, both forms were more than once pretty useful in my calculations. Many thanks for checking my answer.

Comment: Hi Markus, you assume all $x_{m-j+2}=0$ in your general definition of ${\hat B}_j(t)$, right? Further $j=0$ doesn't really make sense; does it follow that ${\hat B}_{m,0}=0$?

Comment: Hi again, your ${\hat B}_j(t)$ reminded me on power symmetric functions, which are mentioned at [Wiki:Bell polynomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Symmetric_polynomials). This is insofar remarkable because, the appearing Bell polynomials are written as $B_{n,k}(e_{1},2!e_{2},3!e_{3},\ldots ,(n-k+1)!e_{n-k+1})$. Here $e_k$ are elementary symmetric functions, which are the scaled [coefficients of the polynomial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Properties) where we once started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2228226/19341)...

Comment: @draks...: Hi! With respect to the comment before: Yes, $\hat{B}_m,0=0$ whenever the index $m$ is not in the appropriate range. With respect to the activities up to now: Despite the connection with the elementary symmetric functions, I don't expect any nice formula similarly to the identity with Bell numbers. Regards,

Comment: Hi, Tom Copeland just remarked that the expression the derivative of the log is related to Faber polynomials (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2283410/19341)), so $\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\log(1+\sum_{k=1}^N n_kx^k)\Biggr|_{x=0}=F_m(n_1,n_2,...n_k)$. 
Further I found $p_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = F_k\bigl(e_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots,e_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\bigr)$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/256584/11856). So if $x_k$ are the roots of the polynomial inside the log (i.e. eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix), we end the power symmetric functions of them. Wouldn't this be a wonderful result?

Comment: @draks...: Very nice! Thanks for the info. This is an interesting connection which I wasn't aware of and is worth investigating.

Comment: @MarkScheuer could you please carify, does $[t^m]f(t)$ mean "coefficient of $t^m$ in $f(t)$", e.g. c.f. equation (1) ? Thanks.

Comment: @Pixel: Yes, $[t^n]$ denotes the *coefficient of* operator. I've added a reference which might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{equation*}%\label{Fall-Factorial-Dfn-Eq}
\langle\alpha\rangle_n=
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)=
\begin{cases}
\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1), & n\ge1\\
1,& n=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha)_n=\prod_{\ell=0}^{n-1}(\alpha+\ell)
=
\begin{cases}
\alpha(\alpha+1)\dotsm(\alpha+n-1), & n\ge1\\
1, & n=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
denote the falling and rising factorials of $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ respectively.

In Theorem 2.1 of the paper [1] below, the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-fall-Eq-inv}\tag{3}
\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\frac{B_{n,\ell}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc,\langle\alpha\rangle_{n-\ell+1})}{(k-\ell)!}
=\frac{\langle\alpha k\rangle_n}{k!}
\end{equation}
for $n\ge k\ge0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ was established.

As a consequence of \eqref{Bell-fall-Eq-inv}, the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-rise-Eq-inv}\tag{5}
\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}\frac{B_{n,\ell}((\alpha)_1, (\alpha)_2, \dotsc, (\alpha)_{n-\ell+1})}{(k-\ell)!}
=\frac{(\alpha k)_n}{k!}
\end{equation}
for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$ was derived in Corollary 2.1 of the paper [1] below.

References

1. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
2. https://mathoverflow.net/a/405003/147732
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262657/945479
4. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261764/945479