# If $f(x) = e^{x^a}$, what is $f^{(n)}(x)$, the $n$-th derivative of $f$ and what is $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f^{(n)}(x)/x^{a-n}$.

Tags: derivatives, induction, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

This is inspired by
[Finding the $18th$ Derivative of a Particular Product at $x = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299863/finding-the-18th-derivative-of-a-particular-product-at-x-0)

If
$f(x) = e^{x^a}$,
what is
$f^{(n)}(x)$,
the $n$-th derivative of $f$
and what is
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f^{(n)}(x)/x^{a-n}$.

I'm sure that this is a duplicate,
but I haven't been able to find it.

My conjecture is that
$f^{(n)}(x)
=f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n(x, a)
$
where
$g_n(x, a)
=a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}
$,
the
$c(a, n, k)
$
are
polynomials in $a$
of degree $n-1$,
and
$g_n(0,a)
=c(a, n, 0)
=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (a-k)
=\dfrac{(a-1)!}{(a-n)!}
$.

Note: 
I just added my derivation of
the recurrence for the
$c(a, n, k)$.
It's messy,
so there is a fair chance of error(s).

Here is what I've done.

The following was done
with Wolfy and
https://www.derivative-calculator.net

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=ax^{a-1}f(x)\\
f''(x)
&=a x^{a - 2} (a x^a + a - 1)f(x)\\
f'''(x)
&=f(x) (a^3 x^{3 a - 3} + (a - 1) a^2 x^{2 a - 3} + a^2 (2 a - 2) x^{2 a - 3} + (a - 2) (a - 1) a x^{a - 3})\\
&=f(x)x^{a-3} (a^3 x^{2 a} + (a - 1) a^2 x^{ a} + a^2 (2 a - 2) x^{ a} + (a - 2) (a - 1)a)\\
&=f(x)ax^{a-3} (a^2 x^{2 a} + ((a - 1) a+a (2 a - 2) ) x^{ a} + (a - 2) (a - 1))\\
&=f(x)ax^{a-3} (a^2 x^{2 a} + 3(a - 1) a x^{ a} + (a - 2) (a - 1))\\
f''''(x)
&=ax^{a-4}f(x)\left(a^3x^{3a}+\left(6a^3-6a^2\right)x^{2a}+\left(7a^3-18a^2+11a\right)x^a+a^3-6a^2+11a-6\right)\\
&=ax^{a-4}f(x)\left(a^3x^{3a}+6a^2(a-1)x^{2a}+a (a - 1) (7 a - 11)x^a+(a - 1) (a - 2) (a - 3)\right)\\
...\\
f^{(n)}(x)
&=f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n(x, a)\\
g_1(x, a)
&= 1\\
g_2(x, a)
&= ax^a+a-1\\
g_3(x, a)
&= a^2 x^{2 a} + 3(a - 1) a x^{ a} + (a - 2) (a - 1)\\
g_4(x)
&=a^3x^{3a}+6a^2(a-1)x^{2a}+a (a - 1) (7 a - 11)x^a+(a - 1) (a - 2) (a - 3)\\
...\\
g_n(x, a)
&=a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\ 
\end{array}
$

It looks like
$g_n(0, a)
=c(a, n, 0)
=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (a-k)
=\dfrac{(a-1)!}{(a-n)!}
$
(the last for integer $a$).

I'm quite sure that
the existence of the $g_n(x, a)$
can be confirmed by induction,
but finding the form of the recurrence,
though probably straightforward,
would take more work
than I am willing to do right now.

Maybe later.

And here it is.

---

If
$f(x)
=\prod_{k=1}^m f_k(x)
$,
then,
removing the "$(x)$",
$\ln f
=\sum_{k=1}^m f_k
$
so, differentiating,
$\dfrac{f'}{f}
=\sum_{k=1}^m \dfrac{f_k'}{f_k}
$
so that
$f'
=\sum_{k=1}^m f_k'\prod_{j=1, j\ne k}^m f_j
$.

Since

$\begin{array}\\
f^{(n)}(x)
&=f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n(x, a),\\
f^{(n+1)}(x)
&=(f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n(x, a))'\\
&=f'(x)ax^{a-n}g_n(x, a)+f(x)a(x^{a-n})'g_n(x, a)+f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n'(x, a)\\
&=ax^{a-1}f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n(x, a)+f(x)a(a-n)x^{a-n-1}g_n(x, a)+f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n'(x, a)\\
&=a^2x^{2a-n-1}f(x)g_n(x, a)+f(x)a(a-n)x^{a-n-1}g_n(x, a)+f(x)ax^{a-n}g_n'(x, a)\\
&=f(x)ax^{a-n-1}(ax^{a}g_n(x, a)+(a-n)g_n(x, a)+xg_n'(x, a))\\
&=f(x)ax^{a-n-1}((ax^{a}+a-n)g_n(x, a)+xg_n'(x, a))\\
\text{so}\\
g_{n+1}(x, a)
&=(ax^{a}+a-n)g_n(x, a)+xg_n'(x, a)\\
\text{Since}\\
g_n(x, a)
&=a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\ 
g_n'(x, a)
&=a^{n-1}a(n-1)x^{a(n-1)-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka-1}\\ 
&=a^{n}(n-1)x^{a(n-1)-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka-1}\\ 
\text{so}\\
g_{n+1}(x, a)
&=(ax^{a}+a-n)(a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka})\\
&+x(a^{n}(n-1)x^{a(n-1)-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka-1})\\
&=(ax^{a}+a-n)a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+(ax^{a}+a-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka})\\
&+a^{n}(n-1)x^{a(n-1)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&=ax^{a}a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+(a-n)a^{n-1}x^{a(n-2)}+ax^{a}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&+(a-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&+a^{n}(n-1)x^{a(n-2)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&=ax^{a}a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+(a-n)a^{n-1}x^{a(n-2)}
+a\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{(k+1)a}\\
&+(a-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&+a^{n}(n-1)x^{a(n-2)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&=ax^{a}a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+((a-n)a^{n-1}+a^{n}(n-1))x^{a(n-2)}\\
&+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}ac(a, n, k-1)x^{ka}\\
&+(a-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&=ax^{a}a^{n-1}x^{a(n-1)}+(a^n-na^{n-1}+na^{n}-a^n)x^{a(n-2)}\\
&+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}ac(a, n, k-1)x^{ka}
+ac(a, n, n-2)x^{(n-1)a}\\
&+(a-n)c(a, n, 0)+(a-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}c(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}kac(a, n, k)x^{ka}\\
&=a^{n}x^{an}+ac(a, n, n-2)x^{(n-1)a}+na^{n-1}(a-1)x^{a(n-2)}\\
&+(a-n)c(a, n, 0)\\
&+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}(ac(a, n, k-1)+(a-n)+kac(a, n, k))x^{ka}\\
\text{Matching}\\
g_{n+1}(x, a)
&=a^{n}x^{an}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c(a, n+1, k)x^{ka}\\
c(a, n+1, n-1) 
&=ac(a, n, n-2)\\
c(a, n+1, n-2) 
&=na^{n-1}(a-1)+ac(a, n, n-3)+(a-n)+(n-2)ac(a, n, n-2)\\
c(a, n+1, 0) 
&=(a-n)c(a, n, 0)\\
c(a, n+1, k)
&=ac(a, n, k-1)+(a-n)+kac(a, n, k)
\quad\text{for }k=1..n-3\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Ever heard of [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/441522/272831) as well.

Comment: Yes I am aware of it. This is enough of a special case that I was hoping for an explicit answer.

Comment: The case [a=-1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18284/5676) is already tricky enough to be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If that's all you want, then it is simple enough to verify this inductively:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\big((a)_nx^{a-n}+\mathcal O\big(x^{2a-n}\big)\big)=f(x)\big((a)_{n+1}x^{a-(n+1)}+\mathcal O\big(x^{2a-(n+1)}\big)\big)$$

where $(a)_n$ is the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{equation*}%\label{Fall-Factorial-Dfn-Eq}
\langle\alpha\rangle_n=
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha-k)=
\begin{cases}
\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1), & n\ge1\\
1,& n=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
denotes the falling factorial of $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ respectively.

In Remark 3.1 of the paper [1] below, the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-1-lambda}\tag{1}
B_{n,k}\Biggl(1, 1-\alpha, (1-\alpha)(1-2\alpha),\dotsc, \prod_{\ell=0}^{n-k}(1-\ell\alpha)\Biggr)
=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^{\ell} \binom{k}{\ell} \prod_{q=0}^{n-1}(\ell-q\alpha)
\end{equation}
for $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$ was concluded.

In Theorem 2.1 of the paper [2] below, the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-fall-Eq}\tag{2}
B_{n,k}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc,\langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1})
=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\langle\alpha\ell\rangle_n
\end{equation}
for $n\ge k\ge0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ was established.

The formulas \eqref{Bell-1-lambda} and \eqref{Bell-fall-Eq} were reviewed in Section 1.3 of the article [3] below.

The formulas \eqref{Bell-1-lambda} and \eqref{Bell-fall-Eq} are equivalent to
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
B_{n,k}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc,\langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1})
=\sum _{j=k}^n s(n,j)\alpha^jS(j,k)
\end{equation}
for $n\ge k\ge0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ at https://mathoverflow.net/a/88071/147732, where $s(n,j)$ and $S(j,k)$ stand for the Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds respectively.

The Faa di Bruno formula (see Theorem 11.4 in the book [4] and Theorem C on page 139 in the monograph [5] below) can be described in terms of the Bell polynomials of the second kind $B_{n,k}\bigl(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1}\bigr)$ by
\begin{equation}\label{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial}\tag{1}
\frac{\textrm{d}^n}{\textrm{d}x^n}f\circ h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(h(x)) B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(x),h''(x),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(x)\bigr), \quad n\ge0.
\end{equation}
Then we have
\begin{align*}
\bigl(\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}\bigr)^{(n)}
&=\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^nB_{n,k}\bigl(\langle\alpha\rangle_1x^{\alpha-1}, \langle\alpha\rangle_2x^{\alpha-2}, \dotsc, \langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1}x^{\alpha-(n-k+1)}\bigr)\\
&=\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^n x^{k\alpha-n} B_{n,k}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc, \langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1})\\
&=\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^n x^{k\alpha-n} \sum _{j=k}^n s(n,j)\alpha^jS(j,k)
\end{align*}
for $n\ge0$, where we used the identity
\begin{equation}\label{Bell(n-k)}
B_{n,k}\bigl(abx_1,ab^2x_2,\dotsc,ab^{n-k+1}x_{n-k+1}\bigr) =a^kb^nB_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1})
\end{equation}
for $n\ge k\ge0$ on page 135 in the monograph [5]. Accordingly, we obtain
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\bigl(\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}\bigr)^{(n)}}{x^{\alpha-n}}
&=\lim_{x\to0^+}\Biggl[\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^n x^{(k-1)\alpha} \sum _{j=k}^n s(n,j)\alpha^jS(j,k)\Biggr]\\
&=\begin{cases}\displaystyle
\sum _{j=1}^n s(n,j)\alpha^jS(j,k), & \alpha>0;\\
0, & \alpha=0;\\
(-1)^n\infty, & \alpha<0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

References

1. B.-N. Guo and F. Qi, *Viewing some ordinary differential equations from the angle of derivative polynomials*, Iran. J. Math. Sci. Inform. **16** (2021), no. 1, 77--95; available online at https://doi.org/10.29252/ijmsi.16.1.77.
2. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Bai-Ni Guo, *Closed formulas and identities for the Bell polynomials and falling factorials*, Contributions to Discrete Mathematics **15** (2020), no. 1, 163--174; available online at https://doi.org/10.11575/cdm.v15i1.68111.
3. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No.124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
4. C. A. Charalambides, *Enumerative Combinatorics*, CRC Press Series on Discrete Mathematics and its Applications. Chapman & Hall/CRC, Boca Raton, FL, 2002.
5. L. Comtet, *Advanced Combinatorics: The Art of Finite and Infinite Expansions*, Revised and Enlarged Edition, D. Reidel Publishing Co., 1974; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-2196-8.
6. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261764/945479.

Comment: Thank you for providing links that are available online.

Comment: The equation (6) is proved in the paper "Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences vol. 132 (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941".