# How to get nth derivative of $e^{x^2/2}$

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials, recursion

I want to calculate the nth derivative of $e^{x^2/2}$. It is as follow:
$$ 
\frac{d}{dx} e^{x^2/2} = x e^{x^2/2} = P_1(x) e^{x^2/2}
$$
$$ 
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{x^2/2} = \frac{d}{dx} (P_{n-1}(x) e^{x^2/2}) = (x P_{n-1}(x) + \frac{dP_{n-1}}{dx})e^{x^2/2} = P_n(x) e^{x^2/2}
$$
So we get recursive relation of $P_n$:
$$ P_n(x) = xP_{n-1} + \frac{dP_{n-1}}{dx}, P_0(x) = 1\tag1
$$
My question is how to solve the recursive relation involving function and derivative. I know generating function for recursion like $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+a_{n-1}$. But I am not sure how to solve $(1)$.

Comment: I think we are looking at the [Hermite polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html) (coincidence?) with imaginary argument, cf. Eqs. (30) in the link with $x \rightarrow i x/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted before this is a variant of the [Hermite polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html). Due to subtle differences, we will adapt the standard derivation from [Arfken](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123846544).

#### Generating function

First
\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{x^2/2}
&=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{(x+t)^2/2}
\tag{1} \\
&=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} e^{(x+t)^2/2} \\
&=
e^{x^2/2} \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{d^n}{dt^n} e^{xt + t^2/2},
\end{align}
This means that the polynomials $P_n(x)$ we are looking for
are just the $n$th coefficients of the Taylor expansion of
$e^{xt+t^2/2}$. In other words,
\begin{align}
e^{xt + t^2/2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{P_n(x)}{n!} t^n.
\tag{2}
\end{align}
The left-hand side is the exponential generating function of $P_n(x)$.

#### Recurrence relations

If we differentiate (2) with respect to $t$,
$$
(x + t) \, e^{xt + t^2/2} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{P_n(x)}{(n-1)!} t^{n-1}
 = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{P_{n+1}(x)}{n!} t^n.
\tag{3}
$$
where the previous n = 0 term is simply equal to zero, allowing for a shift in indices.
Expanding the left-hand side,
\begin{align}
(x + t) \, e^{xt + t^2/2}
&=
(x + t) \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{ P_n(x) }{n!} t^n
\\
&=
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{ x \, P_n(x) }{n!} t^n
+
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{ P_n(x) }{n!} t^{n+1}
\\
&=
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{ x \, P_n(x) }{n!} t^n
+
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{ n \, P_{n-1}(x) }{n!} t^{n}.
\tag{4}
\end{align}
Comparing the coefficients of $t^n/n!$ in (3) and (4) yields
$$
P_{n+1}(x) = x \, P_n(x) + n P_{n-1}(x).
\tag{5}
$$

Similarly, by differentiating (2) with respect to $x$, we get
$$
P'_n(x) = n P_{n-1}(x),
\tag{6}
$$
which is noted by [Barry Cipra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86747).
Combining the two yields the relation by [hermes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/215082/hermes).

#### Explicit formula

An explicit formula is more readily derived from the generating function instead of the recurrence relations:
\begin{align}
e^{xt+t^2/2}
&= e^{xt} \, e^{t^2/2}\\
&= \sum_{s = 0}^\infty \frac{(xt)^s}{s!} \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{t^{2m}}{2^m \, m!} \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty
\left(
\sum_{m = 0}^{[n/2]} \frac{ n! \, x^{n-2m} }{ 2^m \, m! \, (n-2m)! }
\right) \frac{t^n}{n!},
\end{align}
where $[n/2]$ denotes the largest integer not exceeding $n/2$.
Comparing this to (2), we get
\begin{align}
P_n(x) = \sum_{m = 0}^{[n/2]} \frac{ n! \, x^{n-2m} }{ 2^m \, m! \, (n-2m)! }.
\end{align}

#### Relations to the standard definitions

For reference, $P_n(x)$ is related to the standard Hermite polynomials as
\begin{align}
P_n(x)
&= (-i)^n \, \mathrm{He}_n(ix) \\
&= \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2} \, i)^n} \, H_n\left(\frac{ix}{\sqrt{2}}\right).
\end{align}

#### Notes

I recently discovered that the problem is related to [Find an expression for the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=e^{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702), and the above solution is essentially the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193712).

Comment: This is a good and clear answer! You deserve some points for it so you shouldn't have made it community wiki:)

Comment: How do you go from derivating respect x to derivatig respect t? Why are they equal?

Comment: @skan We can do this because the function $\exp[(x+t)^2/2]$ depends on $x$ or $t$ through $x+t$ only, we can then apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 4):

Try proving (by induction) that

$$P_{n+1}=xP_n+nP_{n-1}$$

(Note, this is equivalent to proving that $P_n'=nP_{n-1}$.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method which will work. You have **shown** by a simple argument that

$${P_i}(x) = {P'_{i - 1}}(x) + x{P_{i - 1}}(x),\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,{P_0}(x) = 1,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,i = 1,2,...,n\tag{1}$$

Now let's take a look at the derivatives of $f(x)$ directly

$$\eqalign{
  & {f^{(0)}}(x) = {e^{{{{x^2}} \over 2}}}  \cr 
  & {f^{(1)}}(x) = x{e^{{{{x^2}} \over 2}}}  \cr 
  & {f^{(2)}}(x) = \left( {1 + {x^2}} \right){e^{{{{x^2}} \over 2}}}  \cr 
  & {f^{(3)}}(x) = \left( {3x + {x^3}} \right){e^{{{{x^2}} \over 2}}}  \cr 
  & .  \cr 
  & .  \cr 
  & .  \cr 
  & {f^{(n)}}(x) = {P_n}(x){e^{{{{x^2}} \over 2}}} \cr} \tag{2}$$

The first few terms suggest the formula ${{P'}_i}(x) = i{P_{i - 1}}(x)$ to be true. We may prove this easily by using $(1)$ and induction. According to $(2)$, it is clear that the formula is true for $i=1$. Now suppose it is true for $i=k$, ${{P'}_k}(x) = k{P_{k - 1}}(x)$, and then we shall prove it is also true for $i=k+1$. For this purpose, consider the following

$$\eqalign{
  & {P_{k + 1}}(x) = {{P'}_k}(x) + x{P_k}(x) = k{P_{k - 1}}(x) + x{P_k}(x)  \cr 
  & {{P'}_{k + 1}}(x) = k{{P'}_{k - 1}}(x) + {\left( {x{P_k}(x)} \right)^\prime }  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = k{{P'}_{k - 1}}(x) + {P_k}(x) + x{{P'}_k}(x)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = k{{P'}_{k - 1}}(x) + {P_k}(x) + kx{P_{k - 1}}(x)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = k\left( {{{P'}_{k - 1}}(x) + x{P_{k - 1}}(x)} \right) + {P_k}(x)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = k{P_k}(x) + {P_k}(x)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {k + 1} \right){P_k}(x) \cr}\tag{3} $$

Now combining this new result with $(1)$ we can conclude

$${P_i}(x) =   x{P_{i - 1}}(x) + i{P_{i - 2}}(x),\,\,\,\,\,{P_0}(x) = 1,\,\,\,{P_1}(x)=x,\,\,\,\,\,i = 2,3,...,n\tag{4}$$

Finally, you can use $(4)$ as a recursive relation to derive $P_n(x)$ by a usual systematic procedure. That's all.

Comment: The induction is nice! Thank you.

Comment: @hbp: You're welcome. Thank you too as I noticed some typo errors in Eq.(4) by looking to my answer again due to your notification. I just fixed them! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try $P_n(x)=\Sigma^n_{i=0} a_{n,i}x^i$

Then your equation $(1)$ becomes $\Sigma^n_{i=0} a_{n,i}x^i=x\Sigma^{n-1}_{i=0} a_{n-1,i}x^i+\Sigma^n_{i=0} ia_{n-1,i}x^{i-1}$

Comparing coefficients of $x^i$ gives $a_{n,i}=a_{n-1,i-1}+ia_{n-1,i+1}$

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

We have the multiplicative rule for differentiation: $$\frac{\partial fg}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} g + f \frac{\partial g }{\partial x}$$

Also the "chain rule" or rule for function composition: $$\frac{\partial (g(h))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$$

So we let $g = \exp(h)$, $h = x^2/2$. We see that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = x$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial h} = g$

Now we let $f$ be a polynomial. Differentiating a polynomial and expressing the result is a simple linear thing to do. Each exponent is reduced by one and coefficient multiplied by the old exponent so we can write this as a matrix with the numbers $1,2,3$ in one of the superdiagonals. But multiplication with $x$ is also a matrix operation on the coefficients of a polynomial. So we can rewrite each differentiation as a matrix-vector product and then investigate it's properties in terms of matrix properties and linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

By the Faa di Bruno formula, we have
\begin{align}
\bigl(\operatorname{e}^{x^2/2}\bigr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\operatorname{e}^{x^2/2} B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{x^2/2} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{align}
Therefore, we obtain
\begin{equation}
P_n(x)=\frac{n!}{(2x)^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2^k}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k}.
\end{equation}

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Art. 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi and M.-M. Zheng, *Explicit expressions for a family of the Bell polynomials and applications*, Appl. Math. Comput. **258** (2015), 597--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.02.027.
3. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
4. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some properties of the Hermite polynomials*, Georgian Mathematical Journal **28** (2021), no. 6, 925--935; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/gmj-2020-2088.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Here is another similar problem [How to get nth derivative of arcsinx](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550934/how-to-get-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x).

Comment: @EugeneZhang  See the site at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657751: \begin{equation}
(\arcsin x)^{(n)}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\frac{(n-1)!}{(2x)^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{n-j-1}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad n\ge1.
\end{equation}