# How to get nth derivative of $\arcsin x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, generating-functions, recursion

I want to calculate the nth derivative of $\arcsin x$. I know
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
And
$$ 
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{d}{dx} \left(P_{n-1}(x) \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) = \left(-\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^{}} P_{n-1}(x) + \frac{dP_{n-1}}{dx}\right)\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = P_n(x) \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
Hence we have the recursive relation of $P_n$:
$$ 
P_{n}(x)=-\frac{x}{(1-x^2)^{}} P_{n-1}(x) + \frac{dP_{n-1}}{dx}, \:P_0(x) = 1
$$
My question is how to solve the recursive relation involving function and derivative. I think it should use the generating function, but not sure what it is.

Comment: $$\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left(\arcsin(s)\right)=\lim_{a\to 0}a^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}\arcsin(x+ak){n\choose k}$$

Comment: Hint: Use the Binomial Theorem to expand $(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Hi, have found an answer for your problem?

Comment: No good answer has been found yet

Comment: Try expanding arcsin as an infinite series, differentiating, and converting to hypergeometric function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=v(x)=1-x^2$.
For $k\ge0$, making use of the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials $B_{n,k}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\biggl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\biggr]^{(k)}
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{\operatorname{d}^j}{\operatorname{d} v^j}\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}\,}\biggr) B_{k,j}(-2x,-2,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_j\frac{1}{v^{1/2+j}} (-1)^j2^jB_{k,j}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_j \frac{(-1)^j}{(1-x^2)^{1/2+j}} 2^j \frac{1}{2^{k-j}}\frac{k!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}x^{2j-k}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\frac{k!}{2^k} \frac1{x^k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we acquire
\begin{equation}
(\arcsin x)^{(k+1)}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\frac{k!}{2^k} \frac1{x^k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{k-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}
Equivalently,
\begin{equation}
(\arcsin x)^{(n)}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\frac{(n-1)!}{(2x)^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{n-j-1}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad n\ge1.
\end{equation}
In conclusion, we acquire
\begin{equation}
P_n(x)=\frac{n!}{(2x)^n} \sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{n-j}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad n\ge0.
\end{equation}

References

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
2. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
3. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Answer (score 3):

Let $~P_n(x)~=~\dfrac{2^n}{n!}~\Big(\sqrt{1-x^2}\Big)^{2n+1}~\bigg(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\bigg)^{(n)}.~$ Then its coefficients form the sequence described [here](http://oeis.org/A051288).

Answer (score 1):

Outline of a proof that does not use the recursive relation but does yield the correct answer.

Use Faà di Bruno's formula for $n$-fold derivatives in it's "Bell polynomial" form. This omits the question how the tuples affect the final form of the derivatives, so start with:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(g(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(n)}(g(x)) \cdot B_{n,k} (g'(x),g^{(2)}(x),\cdots)
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
    B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\cdots) = \sum_{\sum_i j_i = k, \sum_\ell \ell j_\ell = n} \frac{n!}{\prod_i j_i!} \prod_i\left(\frac{x_i}{i!}\right)^{j_i}
\end{equation}

Once this is done, it's useful to think about how the tuples in the Bell's polynomial summation are constrained (hint: only 1 term survives).

The final answer you're looking for is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^n (1/\sqrt{1-x^2})}{d x^n} = \sum_{k=1}^n (-)^k \left(\frac12 - k\right)_k \left(1-x^2\right)^{-1/2-k} \frac{(2k-n+1)_{2(n-k)} (2x)^{2k-n}}{(n-k)!}
\end{equation}
where the subbed expressions are Pochhammer symbols.

I think that relating this answer to the expression derived when say $n=4$ is taken or $n=7$ or whatever, you will find that the combinatorial expressions from the explicit $n$ add up in non-intuitive ways to the expression found here, and that in that sense, the setup with the recursive approach should be reconsidered.

Hope someone will find this useful.