# I need help with a problem involving the nth derivative of arcsin x

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I need help with a problem. For context, the section of the textbook the problem is in is about power series. Note that the textbook uses the convention that $f^{(n)}$ represents the $n$th derivative of $f$, and $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x).$ I'll now state the problem exactly as stated in the textbook:

Consider the function $f$ defined by
$f(x) = \arcsin x$, for $\lvert x \rvert \leq 1$.
The derivatives of $f(x)$ satisfy the equation 
$
(1 - x^2)f^{(n + 2)}(x) - (2n + 1)xf^{(n + 1)}(x) - n^2 f^{(n)}(x) = 0$, for $n \geq 1.
$

The coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series for $f(x)$ is denoted by $a_n$. You may assume that the series only contains odd powers of $x$.

$\textbf{a.1)}$ Show that, for $n \geq 1, (n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2} = n^2 a_n.$

$\textbf{a.2})$ Given that $a_1 = 1$, find an expression for $a_n$ in terms of $n$, valid for odd $n \geq 3.$

$\textbf{b})$ Find the radius of convergence of this Maclaurin series.

$\textbf{c})$ Find an approximate value for $\pi$ by putting $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and summing the first three non-zero terms of this series. Give your answer to $\textbf{four}$ significant figures.

I'm stuck on $\textbf{a.1}$. The way the question is formulated makes me think you're not supposed to use the actual derivatives of $\arcsin$ to solve it, but I can't figure out how to do it. I know that $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$,so I was thinking that if I can find a formula for the nth derivative of $f(x)$, I should be good to go. 
I know the derivative of $f(x)$:

$f^\prime(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\arcsin x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- x^2}}$. From here, I can easily also find the second, third, etc. derivatives. However, when I try to come up with a formla for the $\textit{nth}$ derivative, I have a problem. I came up with the following formula:

$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\arcsin x = (-1)^n \prod\limits_{k = 0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2} - k\right)$.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to proveed from here, as I don't know how to evaluate the product $\prod\limits_{k = 0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2} - k\right)$. Anyway, I don't think this is the right approrach, as my textbook hasn't dealt with products yet, only sums. Can anyone help with $\textbf{a.1}$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the recurrence relation $(1 - x^2)f^{(n + 2)}(x) - (2n + 1)xf^{(n + 1)}(x) - n^2 f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ ? Then you can simply set $x=0$ to obtain a.1.

Comment: You made a slight mistake: $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Thanks. I will edit straight away.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I did not think of just letting $x = 0$. Thanks a lot! Seems someone beat you to the actual answer :(

Comment: Yes – I should write answers, not comments :)

Comment: For question b, I used the ratio test, but instead of looking at $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$, I looked at $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+2}}{a_n}$. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given differential equation shows you that

$$
f^{(n + 2)}(0) - n^2 f^{(n)}(0) = 0.
$$

Then using Taylor,

$$(n+2)!\,a_{n+2}-n^2\,n!\,a_n=0.$$

Simplify.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept the answer in a few minutes when I can.

Answer (score 1):

At the site https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4657751, it was derived that
\begin{equation}
(\arcsin x)^{(n)}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\frac{(n-1)!}{(2x)^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{j}(2j-1)!!}{j!}\binom{j}{n-j-1}\frac{x^{2j}}{(1-x^2)^{j}}, \quad n\ge1.
\end{equation}
I believe that this general formula for the $n$th derivative of the function $\arcsin x$ can be applied to solve all your problems.