# What kind of ODE is this

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What kind of ODE is the following one:

$y^{(n)}(t) = \dfrac{x^{(n)}(t)}{f(n)}$

I have never seen such type. Any references would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If $y^{(n)}=\frac{x^{(n)}}{f(n)}$, then $y=\frac{x}{f(n)}+P$ where  $P$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ that can be computed with some additional initial conditions.

Comment: Just that simple?! Thanks!

Comment: I know this might be a bit off topic but this ODE somehow resembles the $n^{th}$ derivative of $e^{x^{2}}$

Comment: May I ask you, @GAUSS1860, to explain and show the resemblance?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-%24n%24-th-derivative-of-%24f%28x%29%3De%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D%24#193730  Refer to **Thomas Andrews** answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$ y^{(n)}(t) = \dfrac{x^{(n)}(t)}{f(n)} $$

then we have

$$ y(t) = \dfrac{x(t)}{f(0)},\quad y^\prime(t) = \dfrac{x^\prime(t)}{f(1)},\quad y^{\prime\prime}(t) = \dfrac{x^{\prime\prime}(t)}{f(2)},\text{ etc.} $$

from which it follows that $f(0)=f(1)=f(2),\cdots$.

So, essentially you have
$$ y(t)=c\cdot x(t) $$

Comment: Thank you sir !